# Set cursor position on contentEditable <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable, cursor-position

I am after a definitive, cross-browser solution to set the cursor/caret position to the last known position when a contentEditable='on' <div> regains focus.  It appears default functionality of a content editable div is to move the caret/cursor to the beginning of the text in the div each time you click on it, which is undesirable.

I believe I would have to store in a variable the current cursor position when they are leaving focus of the div, and then re-set this when they have focus inside again, but I have not been able to put together, or find a working code sample yet.

If anybody has any thoughts, working code snippets or samples I'd be happy to see them.

I don't really have any code yet but here is what I do have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#area').focus(function() { .. }  // focus I would imagine I need.
}
</script>
<div id="area" contentEditable="true"></div>
```

*PS. I have tried this resource but it appears it does not work for a <div>.  Perhaps only for textarea ([How to move cursor to end of contenteditable entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125292/how-to-move-cursor-to-end-of-contenteditable-entity))*

Comment: I didn't know `contentEditable` worked in non-IE browsers o_o

Comment: Yes it does aditya.

Comment: aditya, Safari 2+, Firefox 3+ I think.

Comment: Try Setting tabindex="0" on the div. That should make it focusable in most browsers.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is compatible with the standards-based browsers, but will probably fail in IE. I'm providing it as a starting point. IE doesn't support DOM Range.

```
var editable = document.getElementById('editable'),
    selection, range;

// Populates selection and range variables
var captureSelection = function(e) {
    // Don't capture selection outside editable region
    var isOrContainsAnchor = false,
        isOrContainsFocus = false,
        sel = window.getSelection(),
        parentAnchor = sel.anchorNode,
        parentFocus = sel.focusNode;

    while(parentAnchor && parentAnchor != document.documentElement) {
        if(parentAnchor == editable) {
            isOrContainsAnchor = true;
        }
        parentAnchor = parentAnchor.parentNode;
    }

    while(parentFocus && parentFocus != document.documentElement) {
        if(parentFocus == editable) {
            isOrContainsFocus = true;
        }
        parentFocus = parentFocus.parentNode;
    }

    if(!isOrContainsAnchor || !isOrContainsFocus) {
        return;
    }

    selection = window.getSelection();

    // Get range (standards)
    if(selection.getRangeAt !== undefined) {
        range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

    // Get range (Safari 2)
    } else if(
        document.createRange &&
        selection.anchorNode &&
        selection.anchorOffset &&
        selection.focusNode &&
        selection.focusOffset
    ) {
        range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(selection.anchorNode, selection.anchorOffset);
        range.setEnd(selection.focusNode, selection.focusOffset);
    } else {
        // Failure here, not handled by the rest of the script.
        // Probably IE or some older browser
    }
};

// Recalculate selection while typing
editable.onkeyup = captureSelection;

// Recalculate selection after clicking/drag-selecting
editable.onmousedown = function(e) {
    editable.className = editable.className + ' selecting';
};
document.onmouseup = function(e) {
    if(editable.className.match(/\sselecting(\s|$)/)) {
        editable.className = editable.className.replace(/ selecting(\s|$)/, '');
        captureSelection();
    }
};

editable.onblur = function(e) {
    var cursorStart = document.createElement('span'),
        collapsed = !!range.collapsed;

    cursorStart.id = 'cursorStart';
    cursorStart.appendChild(document.createTextNode('—'));

    // Insert beginning cursor marker
    range.insertNode(cursorStart);

    // Insert end cursor marker if any text is selected
    if(!collapsed) {
        var cursorEnd = document.createElement('span');
        cursorEnd.id = 'cursorEnd';
        range.collapse();
        range.insertNode(cursorEnd);
    }
};

// Add callbacks to afterFocus to be called after cursor is replaced
// if you like, this would be useful for styling buttons and so on
var afterFocus = [];
editable.onfocus = function(e) {
    // Slight delay will avoid the initial selection
    // (at start or of contents depending on browser) being mistaken
    setTimeout(function() {
        var cursorStart = document.getElementById('cursorStart'),
            cursorEnd = document.getElementById('cursorEnd');

        // Don't do anything if user is creating a new selection
        if(editable.className.match(/\sselecting(\s|$)/)) {
            if(cursorStart) {
                cursorStart.parentNode.removeChild(cursorStart);
            }
            if(cursorEnd) {
                cursorEnd.parentNode.removeChild(cursorEnd);
            }
        } else if(cursorStart) {
            captureSelection();
            var range = document.createRange();

            if(cursorEnd) {
                range.setStartAfter(cursorStart);
                range.setEndBefore(cursorEnd);

                // Delete cursor markers
                cursorStart.parentNode.removeChild(cursorStart);
                cursorEnd.parentNode.removeChild(cursorEnd);

                // Select range
                selection.removeAllRanges();
                selection.addRange(range);
            } else {
                range.selectNode(cursorStart);

                // Select range
                selection.removeAllRanges();
                selection.addRange(range);

                // Delete cursor marker
                document.execCommand('delete', false, null);
            }
        }

        // Call callbacks here
        for(var i = 0; i < afterFocus.length; i++) {
            afterFocus[i]();
        }
        afterFocus = [];

        // Register selection again
        captureSelection();
    }, 10);
};
```

Comment: Thanks eye, I tried your solution, I was in a bit of a hurry but after wiring it up, it only places the "-" position at the last focus point (which appears to be a debug marker?) and that's when we lose focus, it doesn't seem to restore the cursor/caret when I click back (at least not in Chrome, I will try FF), it just goes to the end of the div. So I will accept Nico's solution because I know it is compatible in all browsers, and tends to work well.  Thanks a lot for your effort though.

Comment: Do you know what, forget my last response, after further examining both yours and Nico's, yours is not what I asked for in my description, but is what I prefer and would have realised I need.  Yours correctly *sets* the position of the cursor of where you click when activating focus back to the <div>, like a regular textbox.  Restoring focus to the last point is not enough to make a user-friendly entry field.  I will award you the points.

Comment: Works great! Here is a jsfiddle of the above solution: http://jsfiddle.net/s5xAr/3/

Comment: Thanks for posting real JavaScript even though the OP lamed out and wanted to use a framework.

Comment: `cursorStart.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\u0002'));` is a reasonable replacement we think. for the — char. Thanks for the code

Comment: I pasted this code into my existing Electron app and it worked perfectly without changing one character (my div id was already `editable` as in the example, or I would have had to change that).

Answer (score 107):

**This solution works in all major browsers:**

`saveSelection()` is attached to the `onmouseup` and `onkeyup` events of the div and saves the selection to the variable `savedRange`.

`restoreSelection()` is attached to the `onfocus` event of the div and reselects the selection saved in `savedRange`.

This works perfectly unless you want the selection to be restored when the user clicks the div aswell (which is a bit unintuitative as normally you expect the cursor to go where you click but code included for completeness)

To achieve this the `onclick` and `onmousedown` events are canceled by the function `cancelEvent()` which is a cross browser function to cancel the event. The `cancelEvent()` function also runs the `restoreSelection()` function because as the click event is cancelled the div doesn't receive focus and therefore nothing is selected at all unless this functions is run.

The variable `isInFocus` stores whether it is in focus and is changed to "false" `onblur` and "true" `onfocus`. This allows click events to be cancelled only if the div is not in focus (otherwise you would not be able to change the selection at all).

If you wish to the selection to be change when the div is focused by a click, and not restore the selection `onclick` (and only when focus is given to the element programtically using `document.getElementById("area").focus();` or similar then simply remove the `onclick` and `onmousedown` events. The `onblur` event and the `onDivBlur()` and `cancelEvent()` functions can also safely be removed in these circumstances.

This code should work if dropped directly into the body of an html page if you want to test it quickly:

```
<div id="area" style="width:300px;height:300px;" onblur="onDivBlur();" onmousedown="return cancelEvent(event);" onclick="return cancelEvent(event);" contentEditable="true" onmouseup="saveSelection();" onkeyup="saveSelection();" onfocus="restoreSelection();"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var savedRange,isInFocus;
function saveSelection()
{
    if(window.getSelection)//non IE Browsers
    {
        savedRange = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    }
    else if(document.selection)//IE
    { 
        savedRange = document.selection.createRange();  
    } 
}

function restoreSelection()
{
    isInFocus = true;
    document.getElementById("area").focus();
    if (savedRange != null) {
        if (window.getSelection)//non IE and there is already a selection
        {
            var s = window.getSelection();
            if (s.rangeCount > 0) 
                s.removeAllRanges();
            s.addRange(savedRange);
        }
        else if (document.createRange)//non IE and no selection
        {
            window.getSelection().addRange(savedRange);
        }
        else if (document.selection)//IE
        {
            savedRange.select();
        }
    }
}
//this part onwards is only needed if you want to restore selection onclick
var isInFocus = false;
function onDivBlur()
{
    isInFocus = false;
}

function cancelEvent(e)
{
    if (isInFocus == false && savedRange != null) {
        if (e && e.preventDefault) {
            //alert("FF");
            e.stopPropagation(); // DOM style (return false doesn't always work in FF)
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            window.event.cancelBubble = true;//IE stopPropagation
        }
        restoreSelection();
        return false; // false = IE style
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you this actually works!  Tested in IE, Chrome and FF latest. Sorry about the super delayed reply =)

Comment: Won't `if (window.getSelection)...` only test if the browser supports `getSelection`, not whether or not there is a selection?

Comment: @Sandy Yes exactly. This part of the code is deciding whether to use the standard `getSelection` api or the legacy `document.selection` api used by older versions of IE. The later `getRangeAt (0)` call will return `null` if there is no selection, which is checked for in the restore function.

Comment: @NicoBurns right, but the code in the second conditional block (`else if (document.createRange)`) is what I'm looking at.  It will only be called if `window.getSelection` doesn't exist, yet uses `window.getSelection`

Comment: @NicoBurns furthermore, I don't think you'd find a browser with `window.getSelection` but not `document.createRange` - meaning the second block would never be used...

Comment: I completely agree.

Answer (score 21):

**Update**

I've written a cross-browser range and selection library called [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) that incorporates an improved version of the code I posted below. You can use the [selection save and restore module](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/SelectionSaveRestoreModule) for this particular question, although I'd be tempted to use something like [@Nico Burns's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div/3323835#3323835) if you're not doing anything else with selections in your project and don't need the bulk of a library.

**Previous answer**

<strike>You can use IERange (http://code.google.com/p/ierange/) to convert IE's TextRange into something like a DOM Range and use it in conjunction with something like eyelidlessness's starting point. Personally I would only use the algorithms from IERange that do the Range <-> TextRange conversions rather than use the whole thing. And IE's selection object doesn't have the focusNode and anchorNode properties but you should be able to just use the Range/TextRange obtained from the selection instead.</strike>

I might put something together to do this, will post back here if and when I do.

EDIT:

I've created a demo of a script that does this. It works in everything I've tried it in so far except for a bug in Opera 9, which I haven't had time to look into yet. Browsers it works in are IE 5.5, 6 and 7, Chrome 2, Firefox 2, 3 and 3.5, and Safari 4, all on Windows.

http://www.timdown.co.uk/code/selections/

Note that selections may be made backwards in browsers so that the focus node is at the start of the selection and hitting the right or left cursor key will move the caret to a position relative to the start of the selection. I don't think it is possible to replicate this when restoring a selection, so the focus node is always at the end of the selection.

I will write this up fully at some point soon.

Answer (score 18):

I had a related situation, where I specifically needed to set the cursor position to the END of a contenteditable div. I didn't want to use a full fledged library like Rangy, and many solutions were far too heavyweight.

In the end, I came up with this simple jQuery function to set the carat position to the end of a contenteditable div:

```
$.fn.focusEnd = function() {
    $(this).focus();
    var tmp = $('<span />').appendTo($(this)),
        node = tmp.get(0),
        range = null,
        sel = null;

    if (document.selection) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(node);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(node);
        sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
    tmp.remove();
    return this;
}
```

The theory is simple: append a span to the end of the editable, select it, and then remove the span - leaving us with a cursor at the end of the div. You could adapt this solution to insert the span wherever you want, thus putting the cursor at a specific spot.

Usage is simple:

```
$('#editable').focusEnd();
```

That's it!

Comment: You don't need to insert the `<span>`, which will incidentally break the browser's built-in undo stack. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4238971/96100

Answer (score 8):

I took Nico Burns's answer and made it using jQuery:

- Generic: For every `div contentEditable="true"`
- Shorter

*You'll need jQuery 1.6 or higher:*

```
savedRanges = new Object();
$('div[contenteditable="true"]').focus(function(){
    var s = window.getSelection();
    var t = $('div[contenteditable="true"]').index(this);
    if (typeof(savedRanges[t]) === "undefined"){
        savedRanges[t]= new Range();
    } else if(s.rangeCount > 0) {
        s.removeAllRanges();
        s.addRange(savedRanges[t]);
    }
}).bind("mouseup keyup",function(){
    var t = $('div[contenteditable="true"]').index(this);
    savedRanges[t] = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
}).on("mousedown click",function(e){
    if(!$(this).is(":focus")){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).focus();
    }
});
```

```js
savedRanges = new Object();
$('div[contenteditable="true"]').focus(function(){
    var s = window.getSelection();
    var t = $('div[contenteditable="true"]').index(this);
    if (typeof(savedRanges[t]) === "undefined"){
        savedRanges[t]= new Range();
    } else if(s.rangeCount > 0) {
        s.removeAllRanges();
        s.addRange(savedRanges[t]);
    }
}).bind("mouseup keyup",function(){
    var t = $('div[contenteditable="true"]').index(this);
    savedRanges[t] = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
}).on("mousedown click",function(e){
    if(!$(this).is(":focus")){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).focus();
    }
});
```

```css
div[contenteditable] {
    padding: 1em;
    font-family: Arial;
    outline: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contentEditable="true"></div>
<div contentEditable="true"></div>
<div contentEditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: @salivan I know it's late to update it, but I think it works now. Basically I added a new condition and changed from using element's id to element's index, wich should exist always :)

Answer (score 6):

After playing around I've modified eyelidlessness' answer above and made it a jQuery plugin so you can just do one of these:

```
var html = "The quick brown fox";
$div.html(html);

// Select at the text "quick":
$div.setContentEditableSelection(4, 5);

// Select at the beginning of the contenteditable div:
$div.setContentEditableSelection(0);

// Select at the end of the contenteditable div:
$div.setContentEditableSelection(html.length);
```

Excuse the long code post, but it may help someone:

```
$.fn.setContentEditableSelection = function(position, length) {
    if (typeof(length) == "undefined") {
        length = 0;
    }

    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var editable = this;
        var selection;
        var range;

        var html = $this.html();
        html = html.substring(0, position) +
            '<a id="cursorStart"></a>' +
            html.substring(position, position + length) +
            '<a id="cursorEnd"></a>' +
            html.substring(position + length, html.length);
        console.log(html);
        $this.html(html);

        // Populates selection and range variables
        var captureSelection = function(e) {
            // Don't capture selection outside editable region
            var isOrContainsAnchor = false,
                isOrContainsFocus = false,
                sel = window.getSelection(),
                parentAnchor = sel.anchorNode,
                parentFocus = sel.focusNode;

            while (parentAnchor && parentAnchor != document.documentElement) {
                if (parentAnchor == editable) {
                    isOrContainsAnchor = true;
                }
                parentAnchor = parentAnchor.parentNode;
            }

            while (parentFocus && parentFocus != document.documentElement) {
                if (parentFocus == editable) {
                    isOrContainsFocus = true;
                }
                parentFocus = parentFocus.parentNode;
            }

            if (!isOrContainsAnchor || !isOrContainsFocus) {
                return;
            }

            selection = window.getSelection();

            // Get range (standards)
            if (selection.getRangeAt !== undefined) {
                range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

                // Get range (Safari 2)
            } else if (
                document.createRange &&
                selection.anchorNode &&
                selection.anchorOffset &&
                selection.focusNode &&
                selection.focusOffset
            ) {
                range = document.createRange();
                range.setStart(selection.anchorNode, selection.anchorOffset);
                range.setEnd(selection.focusNode, selection.focusOffset);
            } else {
                // Failure here, not handled by the rest of the script.
                // Probably IE or some older browser
            }
        };

        // Slight delay will avoid the initial selection
        // (at start or of contents depending on browser) being mistaken
        setTimeout(function() {
            var cursorStart = document.getElementById('cursorStart');
            var cursorEnd = document.getElementById('cursorEnd');

            // Don't do anything if user is creating a new selection
            if (editable.className.match(/\sselecting(\s|$)/)) {
                if (cursorStart) {
                    cursorStart.parentNode.removeChild(cursorStart);
                }
                if (cursorEnd) {
                    cursorEnd.parentNode.removeChild(cursorEnd);
                }
            } else if (cursorStart) {
                captureSelection();
                range = document.createRange();

                if (cursorEnd) {
                    range.setStartAfter(cursorStart);
                    range.setEndBefore(cursorEnd);

                    // Delete cursor markers
                    cursorStart.parentNode.removeChild(cursorStart);
                    cursorEnd.parentNode.removeChild(cursorEnd);

                    // Select range
                    selection.removeAllRanges();
                    selection.addRange(range);
                } else {
                    range.selectNode(cursorStart);

                    // Select range
                    selection.removeAllRanges();
                    selection.addRange(range);

                    // Delete cursor marker
                    document.execCommand('delete', false, null);
                }
            }

            // Register selection again
            captureSelection();
        }, 10);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 6):

You can leverage [selectNodeContents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/selectNodeContents) which is supported by modern browsers.

```
var el = document.getElementById('idOfYoursContentEditable');
var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = document.createRange();
selection.removeAllRanges();
range.selectNodeContents(el);
range.collapse(false);
selection.addRange(range);
el.focus();
```

Comment: is it possible to modify this code to allow the end user to be able to still move the caret to any position they want to?

Comment: Yes. You should use methods setStart & setEnd on the range object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/setStart

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox you might have the text of the div in a child node (`o_div.childNodes[0]`)

```
var range = document.createRange();

range.setStart(o_div.childNodes[0],last_caret_pos);
range.setEnd(o_div.childNodes[0],last_caret_pos);
range.collapse(false);

var sel = window.getSelection(); 
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to the party with this one, but maybe instead of just manipulating the dom on the frontend you could store whatever the current value of the tag you are edititing in a variable that is not the value that is being rendered to the dom. Then you can detect a page refresh and change the value of the innerHTML of the tag then, or in my case you just need to keep track of the changes and send this to a back end. Perhaps my words won't do any justice so I will write a code example that has worked for my use case.

```
import React, { ChangeEvent, useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface IParentProps {}

const ParentComp: React.FC<IParentProps> = (props) => {
  const [innerValue, setInnerValue] = useState<string>();
  const [ghostValue, setGhostValue] = useState<string>();
  // create some boolean to detect when the enter key was pressed in the input field so that you
  //can remove the input field and add the child component
  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    setInnerValue(event.currentTarget.innerHTML);
    setGhostValue(event.currentTarget.innerHTML);
  };

  const handleGhostChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    setGhostValue(event.currentTarget.innerHTML);
  };

  //handle screen refresh, or send the ghost value to the backend
  useEffect(() => {}, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />

      <ChildComponent handleChange={handleGhostChange}>
        {innerValue}
      </ChildComponent>
    </div>
  );
};

interface IChildProps {
  handleChange: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => void;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const ChildComponent: React.FC<IChildProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <p
      contentEditable="true"
      suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
      onInput={props.handleChange}
    >
      {props.children}
    </p>
  );
};
```

I hope this makes sense if you would like me to revise the answer without the typescript bloat I am willing and able. If this works for you guys please let me know I think this is a much simplier solution then trying to reconfigure the cursor how you want it personally.