# jquery Setting cursor position in contenteditable div

Tags: jquery, focus, contenteditable, caret, cursor-position

The old version of the question is below, after researching more, I decided to rephrase the question. The problem as before is, I need to focus a contenteditable div without highlighting the text, doing straight up focus highlights the text in Chrome.

I realize that people solved this problems in textareas by resetting the caret position in the textarea. How can I do that with a contenteditable element? All the plugins I've tried only works with textareas. Thanks.

Old Phrasing of the question:

> I have a contenteditable element that
>   I want to focus, but only insofar as
>   to place the cursor at the front of
>   the element, rather selecting
>   everything.
>
> `elem.trigger('focus');` with jquery
>   selects all the text in the entire
>   element in chrome. Firefox behaves
>   correctly, setting the caret at the
>   front of the text. How can I get
>   Chrome to behave the way I want, or is
>   focus perhaps not what I'm looking
>   for.

Thanks all.

Comment: This [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area) may help with cursor positioning.

Comment: Are you sure those work on contenteditable. I was not able to get those to work.

Comment: @Mark: i have updated the code to latest jquery and modified the demo to work with rich content.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> **demo**: http://so.lucafilosofi.com/jquery-setting-cursor-position-in-contenteditable-div/

```
      <div id="editable" contentEditable="true">
            <h2>Lorem</h2> <p>ipsum dolor <i>sit</i> 
               amet, consectetur <strong>adipiscing</strong> elit.</p> Aenean.
        </div>
```

---

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('[contentEditable="true"]').on('click', function (e) {
                if (!$(this).hasClass('editing')) {
                    var html = $(this).html();
                    if (html.length) {
                        var range = rangy.createRange();
                        $(this).toggleClass('editing').html('<span class="content-editable-wrapper">' + html + '</span>');
                        var $last = $(this).find('.content-editable-wrapper');
                        range.setStartAfter($last[0]);
                        range.collapse(false);
                        rangy.getSelection().setSingleRange(range);
                    }
                }
            }).on('blur', function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('editing').find('.content-editable-wrapper').children().last().unwrap();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

- **NOTE:** make use of rangy.js https://code.google.com/p/rangy/

Comment: That's an interesting  hack, great idea actually. Thank you. But the contenteditable is a wysiwyg editor, so I can't just substitute a textfield.

Comment: An interesting idea, and valuable for some I'm sure, but this does not answer the question of how to set the carat position on a contenteditable div. Adding a "fake" input box is not really a solution; if I wanted to use an input, I would have used an input.

Comment: does not answer the question. better answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div

Comment: i have updated the code to the latest jQuery version and modified the demo to work as expected also with rich content. without adding extra input or textarea.

Answer (score 30):

Maybe I'm misreading the question, but wouldn't the following do (assuming an editable `<div>` with id "editable")? The timer is there because in Chrome, the native browser behaviour that selects the whole element seems to trigger after the `focus` event, thereby overriding the effect of the selection code unless postponed until after the focus event:

```
var div = document.getElementById("editable");

div.onfocus = function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        var sel, range;
        if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
            range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(div);
            range.collapse(true);
            sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        } else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
            range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(div);
            range.collapse(true);
            range.select();
        }
    }, 1);
};

div.focus();
```

Comment: this is great, but how do I put the focus at the end of the div instead of the front?  http://jsfiddle.net/bq6jQ/1/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599694/how-can-i-type-inside-the-parent-contenteditable-div

Comment: @Squirrl: Change both instances of `range.collapse(true);` to `range.collapse(false);`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it happens because you have used

```
elem.trigger('focus');
```

try to use class or to identify the element on which you want to fire a trigger event.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve that problem after a bit of poking around the DOM.

```
elm.focus();
window.getSelection().setPosition(0);
```

It probably only works on WebKit browsers, but since it is the only source of the problem, I added a conditional (using jQuery)

```
if(!$.browser.webkit) {
    elm.focus();
} else {
    elm.focus();
    window.getSelection().setPosition(0);
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: hmm, not sure why, that doesn't work for me. Tim Down's answer does though.

Answer (score 0):

Set pointer position in pre or div tag:

```js
function setCursor(pos) {
    var el = document.getElementById("asd");
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(el.childNodes[0], pos);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    el.focus();
}

$('button').click(function () {
    setCursor(5);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="asd" contenteditable="true" >
asd
two
</div>
<button>Set caret position</button>
```

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f91341cb-48b3-424b-9504-f2f569f4860f/getset-caretcursor-position-in-a-contenteditable-div?forum=winappswithhtml5

Answer (score 0):

for example for inserting image in cursor position:

```
var insertImgTag = document.createElement("div");
insertImgTag.id = "insertImgTag";
if (document.getSelection().anchorNode != null) {
    document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).insertNode(insertImgTag);}
```

then select created element:

```
$("#insertImgTag")
            .parent()
            .html(
                "<img src=/images/" + $("#name").val() + " width='" + imgWidth + "%' alt='" + imgAlt + "'>"
            );
```