# How can I type inside the parent contentEditable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

How can you type inside a contentEditable div outside of a child contentEditable div without retaining the child's class, and without changing contenteditable to false.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bq6jQ/)

```
<div class ="container" contenteditable="true">        
    <span class="meatball" contenteditable="true">meatball</span>
</div>
```

Should be this:

```
<div class ="container" contenteditable="true">        
    <span class="meatball" contenteditable="true">meatball</span> spaghetti
</div>
```

Not this:

```
<div class ="container" contenteditable="true">        
    <span class="meatball" contenteditable="true">meatball spaghetti</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to click in the red box and type red.

```
    <br><br>

<div class ="container" contenteditable="true">        
    <span class="meatball" id="meatball" contenteditable="true">meatball</span> spaghetti
</div>
<!-- will work with contenteditable="false" but then I can't type blue-->
```

css

```
#meatball{
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    color:blue;
    padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
    font-size:20px;
}

.container{
    border: 1px dashed red;
    color:red;

}
```

Comment: if not what you expected, explain to me what you want to do more specifically

Comment: Click on the fiddle.  Then click inside the red box and type.  It's blue.  I want it to be red.

Comment: if you're in the red div want all these red and blue if you want all blue?

Comment: No man.  I want to type in the red div.  The parent, and not the child.  Look http://jsfiddle.net/bq6jQ/ Click on the red div and type.  The letters are blue, because it is inside the child's div.  I want it to be outside.  To be red.

Answer (score 0):

I changed a little bit of your code, maybe you can try this and I hope it helps you. :)

```
#meatball{
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    color:blue;
    padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
    font-size:20px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.wrapper{
    position:relative;
}
.item{
    line-height:30px;
    min-height:30px;
}
.container{
    border: 1px dashed red;
    color:red;
    padding-left: 150px;
}

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class ="container item" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <div class="meatball w_o_r_d_s item" id="meatball" contenteditable="true">meatball</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this, by adding an invisible character to trick the browser `&zwnj;` http://jsfiddle.net/bq6jQ/4/ . I also add an extra `<span>` to avoid a caret visual bug