# Placing cursor/caret at specific position in a contentEditable onFocus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I'm trying to keep the cursor at specific `character` in `contentEditable` div when `.focus()` event occurs.

That is I've content editable `div(.textA)` with following content:

```
<div class='textA' contentEditable='true'>
Hello There to all <div class='xyz' contentEditable='true'>SO</div> Users.<br>
Can you all Please <div class='abc'>Solve</div> This for me?<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class='xyz'>VT</div>
</div>
```

Then I'm trying to develop a `function placeCaretAt(position)` in `javascript` in such a way that,

it'll place cursor at `position`th character from the `.text()` of that div on `focus` event.

ie, for ex: when it is called as

```
$('.textA').focus(function(){ 
placeCaretAt(20); 
});
```

then it should place cursor in between `S` & `O` of `SO` users like `<div class='xyz' contentEditable='true'>S|O</div>`.

for getting `text` without `tags` from `contentEditable` I use `.text()` of Jquery.

Can experts here please help me? any help/advice/suggestions are welcome :). Thanks in advance.

I had already seen:

[How to set caret(cursor) position in contenteditable element (div)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249095/how-to-set-caretcursor-position-in-contenteditable-element-div)

[jquery Setting cursor position in contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871081/jquery-setting-cursor-position-in-contenteditable-div)

[Set cursor position on contentEditable <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div)

But they were of no use for me. Bad Luck and a day :(. Please Help me experts.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095155/javascript-contenteditable-set-cursor-caret-to-index

Comment: @TimDown, When I said experts, I really meant guys like you. Seriously. I've seen your every answer regarding `contentEditable` and +1'ed it :). I think you've special bond with `contentEditable`'s `caret` :D. But mate In that answer you've only handled `textNodes` my `div` contains more than that. can you please help me?

Comment: Thanks :) Just handling text nodes is the simplest approach but has many drawbacks which I mentioned in the linked answer. I've written a more heavyweight solution for my Rangy library that handles a lot of the complexity: https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Text-Range-Module