# How to write any text with emoticon on contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I changed my `textarea` to `div contenteditable` for display emoticon yet just enter emoticon's value with text. So I used jQuery `.bind`.

Now I cannot enter any text on `contenteditable div` when I write anything on textarea.

Here is my work: ( here 888 is all of my php `'.$id.'` )

```js
var smileys = {
    ':)': '<img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/public/style_emoticons/default/wacko.png" border="0" alt="" />',
 ':-)': '<img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/public/style_emoticons/default/wacko.png" border="0" alt="" />',
 ':D': '<img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/public/style_emoticons/default/wacko.png" border="0" alt="" />',
};

function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
function smilyMe(msg) {
    msg = msg.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
    for (var key in smileys) {
        msg = msg.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(key), "g"), smileys[key]);
    }
    return msg;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#comment").bind("keyup", function(e) {
   var EID = $(this).attr('class').replace('com','');
    $(".com"+EID).html(smilyMe($(".com"+EID).html()));
  });
});
```

```css
#maintbox {
    top:50px;
 position:relative;
 min-height: 38px;
 width: 100%;
}
div.chat {
    width: 100%;
}

#comment {
    font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif;
 font-size:12px;
   min-height: 25px;
   color:#000;
   top:0; left:0; z-index:998; background: transparent;
 border: 2px solid #ccc;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0;
    resize: none;
    padding-right:50px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="maintbox">
  <div class="chat">
   <div contenteditable name="comment" tabindex="4" id="comment" class="com888" placeholder="Type here..."></div>
  </div>
</div>
  
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c0d3.googlecode.com/files/jquery-latest.pack.js'></script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hope this might help u mate.. :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#comment").bind("keyup", function(e) {
    var EID = $(this).attr('class').replace('com','');
    $(".com"+EID).html(smilyMe($(".com"+EID).html()));  //Replaced .val() to .html()
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7waw4eg/)

Comment: Thank u sir. Updated with html but after write any text with :) Textarea cursor starting from beginning.

Comment: Check this link mate..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871081/jquery-setting-cursor-position-in-contenteditable-div

Comment: If you found the answer useful upvote the answers so that it would be helpful for others too.