# Create simple text editor (javascript)

Tags: javascript, text-editor

I would like to create a simple text editor in Javascript. The challenge for me is: the buttons above my text-editor should be adjusted on the content of the DOM. For example: if the cursor is within a 'ul'-tag in my text-editor, only button 'li' should be displayed.

I already created a 'content-editable div', but I don't know where to look next. Can someone help me with some ideas? If I can do this with help of an existing JS-text-editor, please say.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #textEditor {
            border: 1px solid black; display:block; width: 300px; height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var options = ['ul','div'];
        var subOptions = {
            'ul':['li'],
            'div':['div','span', 'p']
        };
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="textEditor" contenteditable="true"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 24):

I Create a simple & rich text editor using the only javascript. Especially I create this for my powerBI custom visual. You can use it in any project.

```js
    function chooseColor(){
      var mycolor = document.getElementById("myColor").value;
      document.execCommand('foreColor', false, mycolor);
    }

    function changeFont(){
      var myFont = document.getElementById("input-font").value;
      document.execCommand('fontName', false, myFont);
    }

    function changeSize(){
      var mysize = document.getElementById("fontSize").value;
      document.execCommand('fontSize', false, mysize);
    }

    function checkDiv(){
      var editorText = document.getElementById("editor1").innerHTML;
      if(editorText === ''){
        document.getElementById("editor1").style.border = '5px solid red';
      }
    }

    function removeBorder(){
      document.getElementById("editor1").style.border = '1px solid transparent';
    }
```

```css
body {
    font: 400 16px/1.4 'serif';
    }
#container #containerHeader{
    text-align: center;
    cursor:move;
}
#container #editor1 {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    height: 100px;
    width: 602px;
    margin: 0px auto 0;
    padding:10px;
   }
#container fieldset {
    margin: 2px auto 0px;
    width: 600px;
    height:26px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border:none;
}
#container button {
    width: 5ex;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px 3px;
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border:none;
}
#container img{
      width:100%;
}
#container .bold{
background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
}
#container .italic{
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
}
#container .underline{
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
}
#container .align-left{
    background-image : url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEsAAAA1CAAAAAAsDUmHAAAAIGNIUk0AAHomAACAhAAA+gAAAIDoAAB1MAAA6mAAADqYAAAXcJy6UTwAAAACYktHRAAAqo0jMgAAAAlwSFlzAAAuIwAALiMBeKU/dgAAAAd0SU1FB+MIHAYHAD13ih8AAAIrSURBVEjHzZaxTxRBFMa/N7OH0FJqSwnChsTYnomKnJUKFOo1JrbGwpBYmwCV0X9AvMRK1IJ4OTtjYyCQ44xWtNpaa9x5z+IIt7vHbGYeV3DlJvfLm2++b76XCEb2S3DGWeJIRxBLJZboJxShAkvo94uuajBJH00ewZIj1J8bu4Y1LLPd/jLRh/VZLtnaPacTjGp7b5suyev1C5zp5CL8LGhPuASnFJ9xGXm9rNRXN0QVAZInV8Tm75FkfeWHSi+eTkueAHGaKv3Fpux7w6xDGTOcx8G3EeQx5m+WKlgiUZZgkJ9Ff9/sB9+jzN8dF/KwhOR2OzyPhrc+mmFYn8X2fXuMw8VPOu+W2HrmwmFUHhMcQjxnJMyAasEZIuAifHpZaTRbMXrduwnru0fCq5WDYL14bqHKq4LFxRh/SZW/yEU8OWQrMwR72jjmWE65DQxmHORRPRdT+S2UT10dKr1a6m2hB5vKfuTm60LXOtveTEj1GJJpLTeczefxG/BPe3u9hhTyOAWj7EeDqUI/Gtxa6Cj1yq7dgcnPJeZDq6vSi9P7pqA9SMYeqv011LXItKyhvRB0+s11QIjp7ZN7+ZjFUb19Ys8cZ9v0voejpmcr3kKhp2sU3h2yuu7tWmc/r8WckTeu1523H3dgI/JY46918ep1HiYJP6PBBa/2Fksv9yL6MZtf9vYjyXjneS+8H2cfT3i1B8nksxiLS2U/ShaxRkvlXjjaPOJMsf4DQ22vjD/V/uUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
    width:40px;
}

#container .align-right{
    background-image:url('data:image/png;base64,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');
    width:40px;
}
#container .align-center{
    width: 38px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-image:url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAOCAYAAAAvxDzwAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAADRJREFUOBFjYGBg2ArE/6mEtzIBDaImADlsCAJSwhSkFgVQGoYjIMwIpdfRdAhJUYMrHQIAWPdBdW2q70gAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
}

#container .redo-apply{
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
}
#container .undo-apply{
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
}
#container .unorderedlist{
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
}
#container .orderedlist{
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
}
#container .strikethrough{
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAeCAQAAACROWYpAAAAAmJLR0QA/4ePzL8AAABFSURBVEjHY2AY2eAww38i4GHsmv8TCXFqxmYYPjVIzj5MUPNhXM7G5Q2ywKhm2mo+TG7ipFjzYAGjiYTs8uwwHTUPZwAAW5aYHd3noZcAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
}
#container .color-apply{
    width: 20px;
}
#container #input-font{
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
}
[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before{
    content:attr(data-text);
    color:#888;
}
#container .loader {
    border: 6px solid #f3f3f3; 
    border-top: 6px solid #3498db; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 20px;
}

/* @keyframes spin {
0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
} */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="custom-text-editor.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="custom-text-editor.css"/>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container" >
    <fieldset>
      <button class="fontStyle italic" onclick="document.execCommand('italic',false,null);" title="Italicize Highlighted Text"></button>
      <button class="fontStyle bold" onclick="document.execCommand( 'bold',false,null);" title="Bold Highlighted Text"></button>
      <button class="fontStyle underline" onclick="document.execCommand( 'underline',false,null);"></button>
      <select id="input-font" class="input"  onchange="changeFont (this);">
        <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
        <option value="Helvetica">Helvetica</option>
        <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
        <option value="Sans serif">Sans serif</option>
        <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
        <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
        <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
        <option value="Palatino">Palatino</option>
        <option value="Garamond">Garamond</option>
        <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
        <option value="Arial Black">Arial Black</option>
        <option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
        <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
      </select>
      <button class="fontStyle strikethrough" onclick="document.execCommand( 'strikethrough',false,null);"><strikethrough></strikethrough></button>
      <button class="fontStyle align-left" onclick="document.execCommand( 'justifyLeft',false,null);"><justifyLeft></justifyLeft></button>
      <button class="fontStyle align-center" onclick="document.execCommand( 'justifyCenter',false,null);"><justifyCenter></justifyCenter></button>
      <button class="fontStyle align-right" onclick="document.execCommand( 'justifyRight',false,null);"><justifyRight></justifyRight></button>
      <button class="fontStyle redo-apply" onclick="document.execCommand( 'redo',false,null);"><redo></redo></button>
      <button class="fontStyle undo-apply" onclick="document.execCommand( 'undo',false,null);"><undo></undo></button>
      <button class="fontStyle orderedlist" onclick="document.execCommand('insertOrderedList', false, null);"><insertOrderedList></insertOrderedList></button>
      <button class="fontStyle unorderedlist" onclick="document.execCommand('insertUnorderedList',false, null)"><insertUnorderedList></insertUnorderedList></button>    
      <input class="color-apply" type="color" onchange="chooseColor()" id="myColor"> 

      <!-- font size start -->
      <select id="fontSize" onclick="changeSize()">
        <option value="1">1</option>      
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
      </select>
      <!-- font size end -->
      
  </fieldset>

  <div id="editor1" contenteditable="true" data-text="Enter comment...."></div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but it is not working on opera mini and UC browsers for android. Is there any other alternative way to do this exec command()?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a contenteditable html element so the user can edit it.

```html
<div id="myDiv" contenteditable = "true" style = "border: 1px solid black">
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;<br>
&lt;html&gt;<br>
&lt;head&gt;<br>
&nbsp;<br>
&nbsp;<br>
&lt;/head&gt;<br>
&lt;body&gt;<br>

&nbsp;<br>
&nbsp;<br>
&lt;/body&gt;<br>
&lt;/html&gt;
</div>

<script>
w3CodeColor(document.getElementById("myDiv"));

function w3CodeColor(elmnt, mode) {
  var lang = (mode || "html");
  var elmntObj = (document.getElementById(elmnt) || elmnt);
  var elmntTxt = elmntObj.innerHTML;
  var tagcolor = "mediumblue";
  var tagnamecolor = "brown";
  var attributecolor = "red";
  var attributevaluecolor = "mediumblue";
  var commentcolor = "green";
  var cssselectorcolor = "brown";
  var csspropertycolor = "red";
  var csspropertyvaluecolor = "mediumblue";
  var cssdelimitercolor = "black";
  var cssimportantcolor = "red";
  var jscolor = "black";
  var jskeywordcolor = "mediumblue";
  var jsstringcolor = "brown";
  var jsnumbercolor = "red";
  var jspropertycolor = "black";
  elmntObj.style.fontFamily = "Consolas,'Courier New', monospace";
  if (!lang) {lang = "html"; }
  if (lang == "html") {elmntTxt = htmlMode(elmntTxt);}
  if (lang == "css") {elmntTxt = cssMode(elmntTxt);}
  if (lang == "js") {elmntTxt = jsMode(elmntTxt);}
  elmntObj.innerHTML = elmntTxt;

  function extract(str, start, end, func, repl) {
    var s, e, d = "", a = [];
    while (str.search(start) > -1) {
      s = str.search(start);
      e = str.indexOf(end, s);
      if (e == -1) {e = str.length;}
      if (repl) {
        a.push(func(str.substring(s, e + (end.length))));
        str = str.substring(0, s) + repl + str.substr(e + (end.length));
      } else {
        d += str.substring(0, s);
        d += func(str.substring(s, e + (end.length)));
        str = str.substr(e + (end.length));
      }
    }
    this.rest = d + str;
    this.arr = a;
  }
  function htmlMode(txt) {
    var rest = txt, done = "", php, comment, angular, startpos, endpos, note, i;
    comment = new extract(rest, "&lt;!--", "--&gt;", commentMode, "W3HTMLCOMMENTPOS");
    rest = comment.rest;
    while (rest.indexOf("&lt;") > -1) {
      note = "";
      startpos = rest.indexOf("&lt;");
      if (rest.substr(startpos, 9).toUpperCase() == "&LT;STYLE") {note = "css";}
      if (rest.substr(startpos, 10).toUpperCase() == "&LT;SCRIPT") {note = "javascript";}
      endpos = rest.indexOf("&gt;", startpos);
      if (endpos == -1) {endpos = rest.length;}
      done += rest.substring(0, startpos);
      done += tagMode(rest.substring(startpos, endpos + 4));
      rest = rest.substr(endpos + 4);
      if (note == "css") {
        endpos = rest.indexOf("&lt;/style&gt;");
        if (endpos > -1) {
          done += cssMode(rest.substring(0, endpos));
          rest = rest.substr(endpos);
        }
      }
      if (note == "javascript") {
        endpos = rest.indexOf("&lt;/script&gt;");
        if (endpos > -1) {
          done += jsMode(rest.substring(0, endpos));
          rest = rest.substr(endpos);
        }
      }
    }
    rest = done + rest;
    for (i = 0; i < comment.arr.length; i++) {
        rest = rest.replace("W3HTMLCOMMENTPOS", comment.arr[i]);
    }
    return rest;
  }
  function tagMode(txt) {
    var rest = txt, done = "", startpos, endpos, result;
    while (rest.search(/(\s|<br>)/) > -1) {
      startpos = rest.search(/(\s|<br>)/);
      endpos = rest.indexOf("&gt;");
      if (endpos == -1) {endpos = rest.length;}
      done += rest.substring(0, startpos);
      done += attributeMode(rest.substring(startpos, endpos));
      rest = rest.substr(endpos);
    }
    result = done + rest;
    result = "<span style=color:" + tagcolor + ">&lt;</span>" + result.substring(4);
    if (result.substr(result.length - 4, 4) == "&gt;") {
      result = result.substring(0, result.length - 4) + "<span style=color:" + tagcolor + ">&gt;</span>";
    }
    return "<span style=color:" + tagnamecolor + ">" + result + "</span>";
  }
  function attributeMode(txt) {
    var rest = txt, done = "", startpos, endpos, singlefnuttpos, doublefnuttpos, spacepos;
    while (rest.indexOf("=") > -1) {
      endpos = -1;
      startpos = rest.indexOf("=");
      singlefnuttpos = rest.indexOf("'", startpos);
      doublefnuttpos = rest.indexOf('"', startpos);
      spacepos = rest.indexOf(" ", startpos + 2);
      if (spacepos > -1 && (spacepos < singlefnuttpos || singlefnuttpos == -1) && (spacepos < doublefnuttpos || doublefnuttpos == -1)) {
        endpos = rest.indexOf(" ", startpos);
      } else if (doublefnuttpos > -1 && (doublefnuttpos < singlefnuttpos || singlefnuttpos == -1) && (doublefnuttpos < spacepos || spacepos == -1)) {
        endpos = rest.indexOf('"', rest.indexOf('"', startpos) + 1);
      } else if (singlefnuttpos > -1 && (singlefnuttpos < doublefnuttpos || doublefnuttpos == -1) && (singlefnuttpos < spacepos || spacepos == -1)) {
        endpos = rest.indexOf("'", rest.indexOf("'", startpos) + 1);
      }
      if (!endpos || endpos == -1 || endpos < startpos) {endpos = rest.length;}
      done += rest.substring(0, startpos);
      done += attributeValueMode(rest.substring(startpos, endpos + 1));
      rest = rest.substr(endpos + 1);
    }
    return "<span style=color:" + attributecolor + ">" + done + rest + "</span>";
  }
  function attributeValueMode(txt) {
    return "<span style=color:" + attributevaluecolor + ">" + txt + "</span>";
  }
  function commentMode(txt) {
    return "<span style=color:" + commentcolor + ">" + txt + "</span>";
  }
  function cssMode(txt) {
    var rest = txt, done = "", s, e, comment, i, midz, c, cc;
    comment = new extract(rest, /\/\*/, "*/", commentMode, "W3CSSCOMMENTPOS");
    rest = comment.rest;
    while (rest.search("{") > -1) {
      s = rest.search("{");
      midz = rest.substr(s + 1);
      cc = 1;
      c = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < midz.length; i++) {
        if (midz.substr(i, 1) == "{") {cc++; c++}
        if (midz.substr(i, 1) == "}") {cc--;}
        if (cc == 0) {break;}
      }
      if (cc != 0) {c = 0;}
      e = s;
      for (i = 0; i <= c; i++) {
        e = rest.indexOf("}", e + 1);
      }
      if (e == -1) {e = rest.length;}
      done += rest.substring(0, s + 1);
      done += cssPropertyMode(rest.substring(s + 1, e));
      rest = rest.substr(e);
    }
    rest = done + rest;
    rest = rest.replace(/{/g, "<span style=color:" + cssdelimitercolor + ">{</span>");
    rest = rest.replace(/}/g, "<span style=color:" + cssdelimitercolor + ">}</span>");
    for (i = 0; i < comment.arr.length; i++) {
        rest = rest.replace("W3CSSCOMMENTPOS", comment.arr[i]);
    }
    return "<span style=color:" + cssselectorcolor + ">" + rest + "</span>";
  }
  function cssPropertyMode(txt) {
    var rest = txt, done = "", s, e, n, loop;
    if (rest.indexOf("{") > -1 ) { return cssMode(rest); }
    while (rest.search(":") > -1) {
      s = rest.search(":");
      loop = true;
      n = s;
      while (loop == true) {
        loop = false;
        e = rest.indexOf(";", n);
        if (rest.substring(e - 5, e + 1) == "&nbsp;") {
          loop = true;
          n = e + 1;
        }
      }
      if (e == -1) {e = rest.length;}
      done += rest.substring(0, s);
      done += cssPropertyValueMode(rest.substring(s, e + 1));
      rest = rest.substr(e + 1);
    }
    return "<span style=color:" + csspropertycolor + ">" + done + rest + "</span>";
  }
  function cssPropertyValueMode(txt) {
    var rest = txt, done = "", s;
    rest = "<span style=color:" + cssdelimitercolor + ">:</span>" + rest.substring(1);
    while (rest.search(/!important/i) > -1) {
      s = rest.search(/!important/i);
      done += rest.substring(0, s);
      done += cssImportantMode(rest.substring(s, s + 10));
      rest = rest.substr(s + 10);
    }
    result = done + rest;
    if (result.substr(result.length - 1, 1) == ";" && result.substr(result.length - 6, 6) != "&nbsp;" && result.substr(result.length - 4, 4) != "&lt;" && result.substr(result.length - 4, 4) != "&gt;" && result.substr(result.length - 5, 5) != "&amp;") {
      result = result.substring(0, result.length - 1) + "<span style=color:" + cssdelimitercolor + ">;</span>";
    }
    return "<span style=color:" + csspropertyvaluecolor + ">" + result + "</span>";
  }
  function cssImportantMode(txt) {
    return "<span style=color:" + cssimportantcolor + ";font-weight:bold;>" + txt + "</span>";
  }
  function jsMode(txt) {
    var rest = txt, done = "", esc = [], i, cc, tt = "", sfnuttpos, dfnuttpos, compos, comlinepos, keywordpos, numpos, mypos, dotpos, y;
    for (i = 0; i < rest.length; i++)  {
      cc = rest.substr(i, 1);
      if (cc == "\\") {
        esc.push(rest.substr(i, 2));
        cc = "W3JSESCAPE";
        i++;
      }
      tt += cc;
    }
    rest = tt;
    y = 1;
    while (y == 1) {
      sfnuttpos = getPos(rest, "'", "'", jsStringMode);
      dfnuttpos = getPos(rest, '"', '"', jsStringMode);
      compos = getPos(rest, /\/\*/, "*/", commentMode);
      comlinepos = getPos(rest, /\/\//, "<br>", commentMode);
      numpos = getNumPos(rest, jsNumberMode);
      keywordpos = getKeywordPos("js", rest, jsKeywordMode);
      dotpos = getDotPos(rest, jsPropertyMode);
      if (Math.max(numpos[0], sfnuttpos[0], dfnuttpos[0], compos[0], comlinepos[0], keywordpos[0], dotpos[0]) == -1) {break;}
      mypos = getMinPos(numpos, sfnuttpos, dfnuttpos, compos, comlinepos, keywordpos, dotpos);
      if (mypos[0] == -1) {break;}
      if (mypos[0] > -1) {
        done += rest.substring(0, mypos[0]);
        done += mypos[2](rest.substring(mypos[0], mypos[1]));
        rest = rest.substr(mypos[1]);
      }
    }
    rest = done + rest;
    for (i = 0; i < esc.length; i++) {
      rest = rest.replace("W3JSESCAPE", esc[i]);
    }
    return "<span style=color:" + jscolor + ">" + rest + "</span>";
  }
  function jsStringMode(txt) {
    return "<span style=color:" + jsstringcolor + ">" + txt + "</span>";
  }
  function jsKeywordMode(txt) {
    return "<span style=color:" + jskeywordcolor + ">" + txt + "</span>";
  }
  function jsNumberMode(txt) {
    return "<span style=color:" + jsnumbercolor + ">" + txt + "</span>";
  }
  function jsPropertyMode(txt) {
    return "<span style=color:" + jspropertycolor + ">" + txt + "</span>";
  }
  function getDotPos(txt, func) {
    var x, i, j, s, e, arr = [".","<", " ", ";", "(", "+", ")", "[", "]", ",", "&", ":", "{", "}", "/" ,"-", "*", "|", "%"];
    s = txt.indexOf(".");
    if (s > -1) {
      x = txt.substr(s + 1);
      for (j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
        cc = x[j];
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if (cc.indexOf(arr[i]) > -1) {
            e = j;
            return [s + 1, e + s + 1, func];
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return [-1, -1, func];
  }
  function getMinPos() {
    var i, arr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      if (arguments[i][0] > -1) {
        if (arr.length == 0 || arguments[i][0] < arr[0]) {arr = arguments[i];}
      }
    }
    if (arr.length == 0) {arr = arguments[i];}
    return arr;
  }
  function getKeywordPos(typ, txt, func) {
    var words, i, pos, rpos = -1, rpos2 = -1, patt;
    if (typ == "js") {
      words = ["abstract","arguments","boolean","break","byte","case","catch","char","class","const","continue","debugger","default","delete",
      "do","double","else","enum","eval","export","extends","false","final","finally","float","for","function","goto","if","implements","import",
      "in","instanceof","int","interface","let","long","NaN","native","new","null","package","private","protected","public","return","short","static",
      "super","switch","synchronized","this","throw","throws","transient","true","try","typeof","var","void","volatile","while","with","yield"];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      pos = txt.indexOf(words[i]);
      if (pos > -1) {
        patt = /\W/g;
        if (txt.substr(pos + words[i].length,1).match(patt) && txt.substr(pos - 1,1).match(patt)) {
          if (pos > -1 && (rpos == -1 || pos < rpos)) {
            rpos = pos;
            rpos2 = rpos + words[i].length;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return [rpos, rpos2, func];
  }
  function getPos(txt, start, end, func) {
    var s, e;
    s = txt.search(start);
    e = txt.indexOf(end, s + (end.length));
    if (e == -1) {e = txt.length;}
    return [s, e + (end.length), func];
  }
  function getNumPos(txt, func) {
    var arr = ["<br>", " ", ";", "(", "+", ")", "[", "]", ",", "&", ":", "{", "}", "/" ,"-", "*", "|", "%", "="], i, j, c, startpos = 0, endpos, word;
    for (i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        c = txt.substr(i, arr[j].length);
        if (c == arr[j]) {
          if (c == "-" && (txt.substr(i - 1, 1) == "e" || txt.substr(i - 1, 1) == "E")) {
            continue;
          }
          endpos = i;
          if (startpos < endpos) {
            word = txt.substring(startpos, endpos);
            if (!isNaN(word)) {return [startpos, endpos, func];}
          }
          i += arr[j].length;
          startpos = i;
          i -= 1;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return [-1, -1, func];
  }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Implementing your own javascript text editor is very challenging, I would recommend you to have a look at the [medium editor](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor)

If you really want to build your own, and you want to know what element the users cursor is in. You will need to use the [selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) API which overall has [great](http://caniuse.com/#search=selection) browsers support.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple text editor:

```
<div class="hb-editor">
  
    <div id="editor-element"></div>

    <textarea id="editor" class="hb-text-editor" style="direction: ltr;"></textarea>

    <div id="editor-view-raw" style="margin: 15px; display: none;"></div>

</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    let editor = new TextEditor(
        '#editor',
        '#editor-view-raw',
        '#editor-element'
    );

    editor.start();

});
```

[image: Screenshot]

Visit https://github.com/Ho3ein83/texteditor for more

Answer (score 0):

This code is about "Simple Text editor". This html code submit to `upload.php`.

This js code converts what `<div id="editor1" contenteditable="true"></div>` typed into a `<textarea id="my-textarea" name="t" style="display:none"></textarea>` value. :

```
 function getContent(){
        document.getElementById("my-textarea").value = document.getElementById("editor1").innerHTML;
    }
```

When this button
`<button class="fontStyle save" onclick="save()"><save>fas fa-save</save></button>` is clicked will direct the relevant data to upload.php from this code. :

```
function save() {
  getContent();
  document.getElementById("save").submit();
}
```

The source code is `Editor.html` :

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
body {
    font: 400 16px/1.4 'serif';
    }
    
#container #containerHeader{
    text-align: center;
    cursor:move;
}
#container #editor1 {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px auto 0;
    padding:10px;
   }
#container fieldset {
    margin: 2px auto 0px;
    width: 80%;
    height:10%;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border:none;
}
#container button {
    width: 5ex;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px 3px;
    height:30px;
    width:40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border:none;
}
#container img{
      width:100%;
}

    </style>
    <script>
    
    
    function chooseColor(){
      var mycolor = document.getElementById("myColor").value;
      document.execCommand('foreColor', false, mycolor);
    }
    
    function backColor(){
      var nColor = document.getElementById("nColor").value;
      document.execCommand('backColor', false, nColor);
    }

    function changeFont(){
      var myFont = document.getElementById("input-font").value;
      document.execCommand('fontName', false, myFont);
    }

    function changeSize(){
      var mysize = document.getElementById("fontSize").value;
      document.execCommand('fontSize', false, mysize);
    }

    function checkDiv(){
      var editorText = document.getElementById("editor1").innerHTML;
      if(editorText === ''){
        document.getElementById("editor1").style.border = '5px solid red';
      }
    }

    function removeBorder(){
      document.getElementById("editor1").style.border = '1px solid transparent';
    }  
    
    function getContent(){
        document.getElementById("my-textarea").value = document.getElementById("editor1").innerHTML;
    }
    
    function save() {
  getContent();
  document.getElementById("save").submit();
}
    </script>
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
    
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" >
    <fieldset>
      <button class="fontStyle cut" onclick="document.execCommand('cut',false,null);" title="cut(Ctrl+x)">&#xf0c4;</button>
  <button class="fontStyle copy" onclick="document.execCommand('copy',false,null);" title="copy(ctrl+c)">&#xf0c5;</button>
  <button class="fontStyle italic" onclick="document.execCommand('italic',false,null);" title="Italicize Highlighted Text">&#xf033;</button>
  <button class="fontStyle bold" onclick="document.execCommand( 'bold',false,null);" title="Bold Highlighted Text">&#xf032;</button>
  <button class="fontStyle underline" onclick="document.execCommand( 'underline',false,null);"> &#xf0cd;</button>
  <select id="input-font" class="input"  onchange="changeFont (this);">
    <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
    <option value="Helvetica">Helvetica</option>
    <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
    <option value="Sans serif">Sans serif</option>
    <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
    <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
    <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
    <option value="Palatino">Palatino</option>
    <option value="Garamond">Garamond</option>
    <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
    <option value="Arial Black">Arial Black</option>
    <option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
    <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
  </select>   
  <button class="fontStyle subscript" onclick="document.execCommand( 'subscript',false,null);"><subscript>  &#xf12c; </subscript></button>
  <button class="fontStyle superscript" onclick="document.execCommand( 'superscript',false,null);"><superscript>    &#xf12b; </superscript></button>
  <button class="fontStyle strikethrough" onclick="document.execCommand( 'strikethrough',false,null);"><strikethrough>  &#xf0cc;</strikethrough></button>
  <button class="fontStyle align-left" onclick="document.execCommand( 'justifyLeft',false,null);"><justifyLeft>&#xf036; </justifyLeft></button>
  <button class="fontStyle align-center" onclick="document.execCommand( 'justifyCenter',false,null);"><justifyCenter> &#xf037; </justifyCenter></button>
  <button class="fontStyle align-right" onclick="document.execCommand( 'justifyRight',false,null);"><justifyRight> &#xf038; </justifyRight></button>
  <button class="fontStyle redo-apply" onclick="document.execCommand( 'redo',false,null);"><redo>&#xf01e;</redo></button>
  <button class="fontStyle undo-apply" onclick="document.execCommand( 'undo',false,null);"><undo>&#xf0e2;</undo></button>
  <button class="fontStyle createlink" onclick="document.execCommand( 'createLink',false,null);"><link> &#xf0c1;</link></button>
  <button class="fontStyle unlink" onclick="document.execCommand( 'unlink',false,null);"><link> &#xf127;</link></button>
  <button class="fontStyle orderedlist" onclick="document.execCommand('insertOrderedList', false, null);"><insertOrderedList>&#xf0cb;</insertOrderedList></button>
  <button class="fontStyle unorderedlist" onclick="document.execCommand('insertUnorderedList',false, null)"><insertUnorderedList>&#xf0ca;</insertUnorderedList></button>    
  <button class="fontStyle save" onclick="save()"><save>fas fa-save</save></button>    
  <input class="color-apply" type="color" onchange="backColor()" id="nColor" title="highlight">
  <input class="color-apply" type="color" onchange="chooseColor()" id="myColor" title="font color"> 
      <!-- font size start -->
      <br>
      font size :
      <select id="fontSize" onclick="changeSize()">
        <option value="1">1</option>      
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
      </select>
      <!-- font size end -->
      
  </fieldset>
<form method="get" id ="save" action="upload.php">
    
    <div id="editor1" contenteditable="true">
    
  </div>
  <textarea id="my-textarea" name="t" style="display:none"></textarea>
 </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `document.execCommand()` function is deprecated. So these answers are also deprecated.

The thing you need now is `document.getSelection()` function.

Answer (score -1):

I make a text editor. Its very super simple editor. Using just simple tricks. Here is jquery full source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HTML page editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/funnel_v2/files/editorscript/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1 class="edit_me_plz" id="jakir">header</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <button class="edit_me_plz btn btn-info" id="button2">Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $(".edit_me_plz").dblclick(function(){
                make_element_editable(this);
            });
        });
        function make_element_editable(me){
            $( '<textarea onblur="set_my_new_text_with_tag(\''+$(me)[0].localName+'\',\''+$(me)[0].id+'\',this)" style="display: block; width: 100%;">'+$(me)[0].innerHTML+'</textarea>' ).insertAfter(me);
            $(me).hide();
        }
        function set_my_new_text_with_tag(prev_ele,id,me){
            $(me).remove();
            $("#"+id)[0].innerHTML = $(me)[0].value;
            $("#"+id).show();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

hope you like it. Happy coding. :)

Comment: The answer just adds an textarea on a click.

Answer (score -1):

```js
<script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function(){
            document.getElementById('sampleeditor').setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
            document.getElementById('sampleeditor2').setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
        });

        function format(command, value) {
            document.execCommand(command, false, value);
        }

        function setUrl() {
            var url = document.getElementById('txtFormatUrl').value;
            var sText = document.getSelection();
            document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">' + sText + '</a>');
            document.getElementById('txtFormatUrl').value = '';
        }
    </script>
    <script>
     function changeFont(){
      var myFont = document.getElementById("input-font").value;
      document.execCommand('fontName', false, myFont);
    }

    function changeSize(){
      var mysize = document.getElementById("fontSize").value;
      document.execCommand('fontSize', false, mysize);
    }
    function changeColor(){
      var mysize = document.getElementById("fontColor").value;
      document.execCommand('fontColor', false, myColor);
    }
    function chooseColor(){
      var mycolor = document.getElementById("myColor").value;
      document.execCommand('foreColor', false, mycolor);
    }
    
    </script>
```

```css
<style>
        .editor
        {
            border:solid 1px #ccc;
            padding: 20px;
            outline: none;
            height: 80%;
        }

        .sample-toolbar
        {
            border:solid 1px #ddd;
            background:#0055FF;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
            padding-top: 15px;
            border-radius:3px;
        }
        

        a {
           padding: 10px 15px;
           background: #0055FF;
           border: 1px solid #0000;
           color: white;
           text-decoration: none;
           font-size: 15px;
           border-radius:3px;
        }
        a:hover {
          color: #ffff;
          background: #000EFF;
        }
        input {
           padding: 10px 15px;
           background: #0055FF;
           border: 1px solid #0000;
           color: white;
           cursor: pointer;
           text-decoration: none;
           font-size: 15px;
           border-radius:3px;
        }
        input:hover {
          color: #ffff;
          background: #000EFF;
        }
        
        
    </style>
```

```html
<div class="sample-toolbar">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" draggable="false" onclick="format('bold')"><i class="fa fa-bold fa-fw"></i>old</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" draggable="false" onclick="format('italic')"><i class="fa fa-italic fa-fw"></i>talic</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" draggable="false" onclick="format('underline')"><i class="fa fa-underline"></i> nderline</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" draggable="false" onclick="format('insertunorderedlist')"><i class="fa fa-list fa-fw"></i> List 1</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" draggable="false" onclick="format('insertorderedlist')"><i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i> List 2</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" draggable="false" onclick="format('strikethrough')"><i class="fa fa-strikethrough"></i> Strikethrough</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" draggable="false" onclick="format('undo')"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i> Undo</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" draggable="false" onclick="format('redo')"><i class="fa fa-redo"></i> Redo</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" draggable="false" onclick="format('justifyLeft')"> <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i> Align Left</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" draggable="false" onclick="format('justifyCenter')"> <i class="fas fa-align-center"></i> Align Center</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" draggable="false" onclick="format('justifyRight')"> <i class="fas fa-align-right"></i> Align Right</a>
        <select id="input-font" class="input"  title="Change Font" onchange="changeFont (this);" style= "outline: none;height: 30px;" >
        <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
        <option value="Helvetica">Helvetica</option>
        <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
        <option value="Sans serif">Sans serif</option>
        <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
        <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
        <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
        <option value="Palatino">Palatino</option>
        <option value="Garamond">Garamond</option>
        <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
        <option value="Arial Black">Arial Black</option>
        <option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
        <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
      </select>
      
      
     <select  id="fontSize" onclick="changeSize()" title= "Change Font Size" style= "outline: none;height: 30px;" >
        
        <option value selected disabled> Change Font Size</option>      
        <option value="2">3</option>
        <option value="3">4</option>
        <option value="4">6</option>
        <option value="5">9</option>
        <option value="6">10</option>
        <option value="7">12</option>
        <option value="8">16</option>
      </select>
     <input draggable="false"  type="color" onchange="chooseColor()" id="myColor" value= "text color" title= "Change Text Color">

</div>

<div class="editor" id="sampleeditor">
    </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
        for(let i = 0; i < yourCodeOptions.length; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll("yourCodeOptions")[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function()
{
switch(this.id) {case "ul": document.querySelector("button.li").style.display="block"; //li tag should be "display: none;" before this}
    }
```