# Simulate backspace button JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a custom backspace button with the same logic as "backspace" button on a keyboard. I use the following code:

```js
function backSpace()
{
    var e = jQuery.Event("keyup");
    e.which = 8; // # Some key code value
    e.keyCode = 8;
    $("mainDiv").trigger(e);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script src="formulas.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0 user-scalable=no"/>
    </head>

    <button onclick="backSpace()">backSpace</button>
    <body id="main" spellcheck="false">
        <div id = "mainDiv" contenteditable="true"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I spend a lot of time for this problem, but I haven't solved it yet. Help me, please.

Comment: Try putting your live example [in your question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) instead of linking to a third party site like JS Fiddle.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17475636/19068

Comment: what exactly do you want this button to do when clicked?

Comment: Do you want to use the button to delete letters from some text or to load the previous page in the browser?

Comment: @jackbox i want the same logic like keyboard backspace button

Comment: `mainDiv` is not any tag name and you haven't used any selector sign (.# etc.) with this. This might be your problem.

Comment: @CosLu i want to delete letters

Comment: `button` should be inside `body`.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki i create this button only for test, then i will delete it

Comment: Be careful when using jQuery. To refer to an id you should use "#id" not just "id".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addition to @CosLu's Answer

#### [JSBin Here also](http://jsbin.com/huwiquleku/edit?html,js,output)

```js
function backSpace() {
  p = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
  c = getCaretPosition(p);
  console.log(getCaretPosition(p));
  str = $("#mainDiv").html();
  if (c > 0 && c <= str.length) {
    $("#mainDiv").focus().html(str.substring(0, c - 1) + str.substring(c, str.length));

    p.focus();
    var textNode = p.firstChild;
    var caret = c - 1; 
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(textNode, caret);
    range.setEnd(textNode, caret);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  }
}

$.fn.setCursorPosition = function(pos) {
  this.each(function(index, elem) {
    if (elem.setSelectionRange) {
      elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
    } else if (elem.createTextRange) {
      var range = elem.createTextRange();
      range.collapse(true);
      range.moveEnd('character', pos);
      range.moveStart('character', pos);
      range.select();
    }
  });
  return this;
};

function getCaretPosition(editableDiv) {
  var caretPos = 0,
    sel, range;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
      range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      if (range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode == editableDiv) {
        caretPos = range.endOffset;
      }
    }
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    if (range.parentElement() == editableDiv) {
      var tempEl = document.createElement("span");
      editableDiv.insertBefore(tempEl, editableDiv.firstChild);
      var tempRange = range.duplicate();
      tempRange.moveToElementText(tempEl);
      tempRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", range);
      caretPos = tempRange.text.length;
    }
  }
  return caretPos;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="backSpace()">backSpace</button>
  <div id="mainDiv" contenteditable="true">aahahtext</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks again! But i have trouble, when insert special symbol. When I insert "sigma" and then click "backSpace" button i see wrong logic (function delete wrong character). To right logic I have to set caret position manually and then click "backSpace". See attached.  http://jsbin.com/kefutuvuci/edit?html,js,output

Comment: it's because when you insert sigma, carat position in `backspace()` resets to 1.

Comment: @shyammakwana.me : although its for content editable, it doesn't work for lets say <b> tag :(

Answer (score 6):

This code works fine for me.
You can clear letter by letter at caret position or clear a selection

```js
var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');

function backspace()
{
var ss = textbox.selectionStart;
var se = textbox.selectionEnd;
var ln  = textbox.value.length;

var textbefore = textbox.value.substring( 0, ss );    //text in front of selected text
var textselected = textbox.value.substring( ss, se ); //selected text
var textafter = textbox.value.substring( se, ln );    //text following selected text

if(ss==se) // if no text is selected
{
textbox.value = textbox.value.substring(0, ss-1 ) + textbox.value.substring(se, ln );
textbox.focus();
textbox.selectionStart = ss-1;
textbox.selectionEnd = ss-1;
}
else // if some text is selected
{
textbox.value = textbefore + textafter ;
textbox.focus();
textbox.selectionStart = ss;
textbox.selectionEnd = ss;
}

}
```

```html
<textarea id="textbox"></textarea>
<div class="button" onclick="backspace()" > BACKSPACE_BUTTON </div>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

**Solution for input**.

```js
backSpace = function ()
{
    var str= $("#text_input").val();
    var position = document.getElementById('text_input').selectionStart-1;

    str = str.substr(0, position) + '' + str.substr(position + 1);
    $("#text_input").val(str);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="backSpace()">backSpace</button>
<input type='text' id='text_input' value='123456789'/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! But need solution for div tag :(

Answer (score 1):

Just update your js to make it work. I have found a snippet to look for the caret position here: [Get caret position in contentEditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972014/get-caret-position-in-contenteditable-div)

Note that the following code assumes:

- There is always a single text node within the editable  and no
  other nodes
- The editable div does not have the CSS white-space property set to pre

```js
function backSpace()
{
    p = document.getElementById ("mainDiv");
    c = getCaretPosition(p);
    str= $("#mainDiv").html();
    if(c>0 && c<=str.length){
      $("#mainDiv").html(str.substring(0,c-1)+ str.substring(c,str.length));
    }
}

function getCaretPosition(editableDiv) {
  var caretPos = 0,
sel, range;
  if (window.getSelection) {
sel = window.getSelection();
if (sel.rangeCount) {
  range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  if (range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode == editableDiv) {
    caretPos = range.endOffset;
  }
}
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
range = document.selection.createRange();
if (range.parentElement() == editableDiv) {
  var tempEl = document.createElement("span");
  editableDiv.insertBefore(tempEl, editableDiv.firstChild);
  var tempRange = range.duplicate();
  tempRange.moveToElementText(tempEl);
  tempRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", range);
  caretPos = tempRange.text.length;
}
  }
  return caretPos;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script src="formulas.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0 user-scalable=no"/>
    </head>

    
    <body id="main" spellcheck="false">
        <button onclick="backSpace()">backSpace</button>
        <div id = "mainDiv" contenteditable="true">aahahtext</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about caret position? I mean OP seems to provide button just for example

Comment: Thank you for answering, but i have to delete character right to cursor position, not the last character in div tag

Comment: So you should have the data on a textarea or input field. From your example it looks like it should be inside a div..

Comment: @CosLu yes, in my case in should be div tag

Comment: @NikitaErmolenko I have updated my answer to take care of the caret position.

Comment: Not work properly, try to add 123456 and remove 4 the 6 will disapear also.

Comment: Yes my bad.. better now?

Comment: @CosLu Sorry, i was wrong. I want to delete one left element(not right) from cursor position. Sorry for my English.

Comment: @NikitaErmolenko isn't this already happening? If i put the caret after the X and click the button the x gets deleted.

Comment: @CosLu yes, it's right, but if i put the caret at end of string and then click the button nothing to happen. And if i delete symbol cursor position haven't to move to begin on string.

Comment: @NikitaErmolenko yes c<=str.length should be used instead of c<str.length. To re-set the position of the caret i'm afraid you will need another piece of code :( Check it here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2948573/2042240

Answer (score 1):

That would be a solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/nezkbws7/2/

```
function backSpace()
{
  var txt = $("#mainDiv").text();
  txt = txt.substr(0,txt.length-1)
  $("#mainDiv").text(txt);
}
```

I created the backspace functionality manually, not with copying the event.

Comment: Need to delete left element from cursor position only.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`document.execCommand('delete')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) to send a backspace:

```js
document.querySelector('#whatever-element').focus(); // focus if needed
document.execCommand('delete');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#sup").on("keydown", function (e) {
if (e.which == 8 || e.keyCode === 8) {
selection = window.getSelection();
selection.modify("extend", "backward", "character");
selection.deleteFromDocument();
  }
});
```

the caret needs to exist inside the text area for it to work.