# How to focus after image when click on any particular image in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, caret

How can we set caret position right after image if we click image.

**Javascipt + JQuery**

```
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      console.log("hiiii");
      $('.demo').append('<span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/NewTux.svg"/></span>')
    }
```

**CSS**

```
    div {
      height: 100px;
      background: #dadadada;
    }

    img {
      border: 1px solid red;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
      margin-right:3px;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

this is jsfiddle link 
http://jsfiddle.net/mustkeom/by6tkrfL/10/

If I click on image I want cursor to move to right to image. But as of now cursor just dont move. It only set its position if i click execly between the images. Any help is appreciate. Please sugest how can we do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery Setting cursor position in contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871081/jquery-setting-cursor-position-in-contenteditable-div)

Comment: @SarvanKumar this is diffrent question because we are focusing on the particular element when clicked