# Javascript Set Caret in ContentEditable Div

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, caret

I have a div tag that is contenteditable so that users can type in the div. There is a function that adds a link into the div when the user presses a button. I would like the caret to be positioned after the link so that users can continue to type. The link can be inserted many times.

Example Code:

```
<div id="mydiv" contenteditable="true" tabindex="-1">before <a href="#">link</a> after</div>
```

I require this code to work in: IE, Firefox, Opera, Safari and Chrome.

Can anyone offer any help?

Comment: See: [Set cursor position on contentEditable <div>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a reference to the `<a>` element you've inserted in a variable called `link`:

```
function setCaretAfter(el) {
    var sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
        range = document.createRange();
        range.setStartAfter(el);
        range.collapse(true);
        sel = window.getSelection(); 
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(el);
        range.collapse(false);
        range.select();
    }
}

setCaretAfter(link);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Tim. I tried the code below but cant get it to work in Firefox on windows :(

<style type="text/css">
*.unselectable {-moz-user-select: none;-khtml-user-select: none;-webkit-user-select: none;user-select: none;}
</style>

<div id="mydiv" contenteditable="true" tabindex="-1">before <a href="#" id="test_53">link</a> after</div>
<button unselectable="on" onclick="setCaretAfter(document.getElementById('mydiv'));">test</button>

Comment: You need `class="unselectable"` in your button start tag.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I tried that but no luck:  <div id="mydiv" contenteditable="true" tabindex="-1">before <a href="#" id="test_53">link</a> after</div>
 <button unselectable="on" class="unselectable" onclick="setCaretAfter(document.getElementById('test_53'));">test</button>

Comment: Just to update: The script does actually place the caret in the correct position just you cant see it.

Answer (score 0):

I looked inside the CKEditor (http://ckeditor.com/) code and found that it has an appendBogus() function as well as inserts an extra <br><span> </span></br> that is then deleted.

The problem of course is that Gecko/IE browsers also have nuances about how <br> tags work too (i.e. whether to use \r or \n to insert into the range vs. adding an <br> element)

You can read through the _source/plugins/enterkey/plugin.js to see the different nuances with handling IE & Gecko.  It seems like one big hack...