# How do I set the caret/cursor position on a specific contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript

I need another function that calls window.getSelection() so this needs to return an appropriate value based on the cursor position in the CED

Comment: duplicate? ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div

Comment: The suggestion near the bottom does not seem to work for me.  somehow, the offsets are reset to 0 by the time I access the saved range.

Comment: Please clarify what you actually need to do, maybe with example code. Also, which browsers do you need to work with?

Comment: Chrome at this point, but that list may be expanded later.  After deleting a contenteditable div, I need to reconstruct it, which includes placing the cursor in the same position it was in before the div was deleted.  I have tried the example code in the link above in several different ways, but it doesn't seem to work.  It doesn't seem like calling "addRange" on window.getSelection() has any effect.

Comment: If the nodes the Range references in its `startContainer` and `endContainer` properties no longer exist, the Range adjusts itself.

Comment: This is one of the hardest things to do in JS, cross browser. I highly recommend you use existing libraries (like rangy) and work your UI around the limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is as good as you're going to get... [Set cursor position on contentEditable <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div/3323835#3323835)