# How can I get HTML-Code in a contentEditable-DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a contentEditable-DIV I try to get the HTML-Code from strat-Position 0 to end-position where the user has clicked.

```
<div id="MyEditableId" contentEditable="true">
  1. Some text 123. <span style="background-color: #0CF;">text 123</span> 456 <span style="background-color: #9F3;">2-> abc </span>
    <br />
    <p> E.g. here is clicked: "click" Text after click </p>
    <p></p>
    <br />
    end of text.
</div>
```

Something as below code snippet, which delivers the text from 0 to end of clicked node. But I need also the HTML-Code in contentEditable-DIV.

```
$('#MyEditableId').on('mouseup', function(event) {
    var MyEditable = document.getElementById('MyEditableId');
    MyEditable.focus();
    range = document.createRange();

    // endOffset: It will be better the length of where actually was clicked, e.g. after 15-characters. But this.length will be also ok.
    endOffset = $(this).length;
    range.setStart(MyEditable.firstChild,0);
    range.setEnd(event.target,endOffset);
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.addRange(range);

    // Below I get the selected text from 0 to end of clicked node. But I need the selected HTML-Code from 0 to end of clicked position.
    alert( window.getSelection() );
});
```

I expect for the result something as follows:

```
 1. Some text 123. <span style="background-color: #0CF;">text 123</span> 456 <span style="background-color: #9F3;">2-> abc </span>
    <br />
    <p> E.g. here is clicked: "click"
```

How can I get the HTML-Code instead of text in my contentEditable-DIV?
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the div and use its property `innerHTML`

http://jsfiddle.net/at917rss/

```
<div id="MyEditableId" contentEditable="true">
  1. Some text 123. <span style="background-color: #0CF;">text 123</span> 456 <span style="background-color: #9F3;">2-> abc </span>
    <br />
    <p> E.g. here is clicked: "click" Text after click </p>
    <p></p>
    <br />
    end of text.
</div>

    $('#MyEditableId').on('mouseup', function(event) {
        var MyEditable = document.getElementById('MyEditableId');
        MyEditable.focus();
        range = document.createRange();

        // endOffset: It will be better the length of where actually was clicked, e.g. after 15-characters. But this.length will be also ok.
        endOffset = $(this).length;
        range.setStart(MyEditable.firstChild,0);
        range.setEnd(event.target,endOffset);
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.addRange(range);

        // get html for your div  
        var myDiv = document.getElementById('MyEditableId');
        alert(myDiv.innerHTML);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I won't the entire content of DIV e.g. `$('#MyDiv').html()`. I will get the content of Div from 0 position to clicked position as HTML-Code, NOT as text.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444430/how-to-get-a-word-under-cursor-using-javascript, it shows how to select html using the cursor, I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the alert line in your code to below one works well..

```
alert($.trim($('<div>').append(range.cloneContents()).html()));
```

Comment: Yes, it is :-) Thanks! But do you know how can I get the content of DIV until EXACTLY `click`?

Comment: 'range' variable in the code mentioned in the question does give the content until click.. No?

Answer (score 0):

I was just going through the documentation for [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range) and [selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection). You could use the `extractContents()` or `cloneContents()` method supported by the `Range` object like so in your case [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4qu5aonv/):

```
 var fragment = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).extractContents();
```

This automatically gets the first range that the user has selected. Although users can select multiple ranges by holding down the "Ctrl" Key. This gives the exact match till the cursor position for the simpler cases.

There are some caveats to this though. Both the methods `extractContents()` or `cloneContents()` return a [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) and the documentation clearly states that:

> Event Listeners added using DOM Events are not copied during cloning. HTML attribute events are duplicated as they are for the DOM Core cloneNode method. HTML id attributes are also cloned, which **can** lead to an **invalid document** through cloning.

In essence, document fragments **can** contain invalid `HTML` and therefore you can not use all the normal `DOM` like `.html()` in some cases.

I found a [relevant SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7232871/1083314) on getting the cursor position on a contentEditable element and came across a [TextRange Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535872(v=vs.85).aspx#properties) (supported in IE < 9) and it has an [htmlText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533874(v=vs.85).aspx) property which returns the HTML source of the selection as a 'valid' HTML fragment. So in that case you would do something like:

```
 var fragment = document.selection.createTextRange().htmlText;
```

However since most of the modern browsers [support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7010417/1083314) `Window.getSelection()`, it's good practice that you use it and build upon the suitable methods you have at your disposal. Hope it gets you started in the right direction.

*Sidenote* - Also from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection):

> using a selection object as the argument to window.alert will call the object's toString method

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. It is helpful. But  `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents();` delivers nothing (maybe it is to change a little) and the `document.body.createTextRange().htmlText;`delivers the entire HTML-Code.

Comment: @user3815508, I was giving you an example of `TextRange` object. I have edited the code snippet as per your context and also included a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qu5aonv/) in the answer that you might want logs the document fragment from the selection into the console. Feel free to play around with it.