# contentEditable div display: none / block focus problem on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, focus, contenteditable

I have a `contentEditable div` which in some cases gets `display: none`, then again `display: block` (`inline-block`), I use `div.focus()` when `display` is set to `block`, but cursor is at the beggining of the text and I can't change its position to end on Chrome.

How can I make it to set cursor at the end, when the div gets focus?

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1181700/912019
Is this what you require ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses jQuery but can be generalised to normal JavaScript. The important part is:

```
var range = document.createRange(),
    selection = window.getSelection();

range.setStartAfter(div.lastChild); // set cursor

selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range); // apply cursor position
```

http://jsfiddle.net/te93D/1/

Comment: This won't work in IE < 9 (in common with so many things), although it's unclear from the question whether this is a problem or not.