# Modify Code That Changes words on keystroke to work in contenteditable instead of textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, innerhtml, contenteditable

If have this code here:

```
$(function() {
   $("#a").keyup(function(e) {
      var updatedText = this.value.replace(
      /(^|[^>])(hello)($|[^<])/gi, "$1<b>$2</b>$3");
      if (updatedText != this.value)
         this.value = updatedText;
   });
});
```

It functions as to take the last word typed that matches the RegExp (in this case the word hello) and adds `<b>` tags around it. This works great in a Textarea (demo here: http://jsbin.com/ibecel/2/edit
But I cannot seem to modify it to work in a contenteditable div. How would I need to modify it to work in a contenteditable div? I tried changing the `value` object to `innerHTML` and `innerText` but to no avail. It always looses focus after the word is typed, or doesn't exit the new things made. PLEASE HELP

Comment: Is the idea for the `<b>` tags to actually display as text that the user can see, or to cause "hello" to become bold? If you want to see the actual string "<b>" you should use "&lt;b&gt;". Also, definitely use `innerHTML` rather than `value`.

Answer (score 0):

I made this modified version: http://jsbin.com/amazaq/2/edit - innerHTML is all you need.

However you are in trouble with the cursor position. That is a harder problem - have a look at [Set cursor position on contentEditable <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div)