# Displaying and editing HTML code in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, richtextbox

I have a DataGridView that is bound to a DataSet. The DataSet has its data from an XML file. In the XML file there is one element that contains basic html data (only `<p>` and `<strong>`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entries>
    <entry>
        <desc><![CDATA[[<p>Some <strong>text.</strong></p>]]></desc>
    </entry>
</entries>
```

When I have a DataGridView that has a column bound to this field `desc` the html gets displayed as string with its tags (`<p>Some <strong>text.</strong></p>`). When I save this xml back, the tags are converted to their html entities.

How can I display the html code as rich text in the textbox ("Some **text**.")? I guess I need to make a custom richtextbox column type here but I'm a little bit stuck as beginner. Furthermore the text should be editable with a richtexteditor.

Can someone give me some help on this?

Comment: You may try using any rich textbox editor, e.g. with jquery plugin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159965/jquery-minimal-rich-textbox-plugin

Comment: I'd personally look at some sort of master-detail design rather than a rich textbox column. Even if there were an out of the box rich textbox column, I imagine the user experience would never be that great. Instead I'd show all the standard grid style data in the datagridview and have a separate rich textbox below the grid for editing the xml data.

Comment: Oh, and I also just added the winforms tag - pretty sure this is correct since datagridview is a winforms control. Sorry if that was wrong.

Comment: @David, I think you are right. The user experience of editing a richtextbox within a DataGridView is rather bad, so I followed your hint on providing a separate edit mask. However, I'm also stuck here. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224556/how-to-edit-a-dataset-in-a-new-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not doing this. It's not a good user experience to have a RichTextBox right in the DataGridView. I finally made it a regular text field that is editable in a separate form.