# How to edit a DataSet in a new Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm a beginner in .NET and C#, so I'm stuck with a problem that might be pretty simple to solve(?).

I'm having a Xml-File as DataSource. I managed to display that data in a DataGridView. On double click I open a new Form that serves as edit mask. But how can I pass the DataSet-entry to the edit form and sync it back to the DataGridViews underlying DataSource when I hit the "OK"-Button in the Edit form?

This is what I have so far:

Main Form:

```cs
public partial class Main : Form
{
    private DataSet dataSet;
    private EditForm editForm;

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void readXmlFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // bind DataGridView to Xml file data
        this.dataSet = new DataSet();
        this.dataSet.ReadXml("data.xml");

        DataTableCollection tables = this.dataSet.Tables;
        DataView view1 = new DataView(tables[0]);

        BindingSource source1 = new BindingSource();
        source1.DataSource = view1;
            source1.Filter = "type = 'editable'";
        gridView.DataSource = source1;
    }

    private void gridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView grid = (DataGridView)sender;
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).Row;

        this.editForm = new EditForm(row);
        editForm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

and this is my edit form:

```cs
public partial class EditForm : Form
{
    DataRow dataRow;

    public EditForm(DataRow dataRow)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.dataRow = dataRow;
            textBoxHeadline.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.dataRow, "headline");
    }

    private void buttonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // update DataGridView and DataSet?
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does your editForm need your entire dataSet? Why don't you just pass it your dataRow and when you're done (user clicked 'OK') you just retrieve that dataRow back from the form.

Comment: Because I'm a newbie and didn't knew what's the best approach to do it.

Comment: instead of getting the row from dataview, get it from the data set. and pass it to new form. As objects are passed by ref, any changes on the edit form will be accepted in the table.

Comment: @Dzire: but doesn't `((DataRowView)grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).Row` reference the DataRow from the DataSet?
@Team-JoKi: I updated my example according to your recommendations and added a binding to a field, but the field does not update.