# What's wrong: Unable insert the em or any tag once while on keyup via innerHtml in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have one big issue, I want to add `em` tag after a while, this occurs on `keyup` event in jQuery. So I want to add `em` tag, and append the rest of the text or chars inside it. This is my code:

```
$(this).text.innerHtml("<em></em>").append($(this).text);
```

Comment: What type of tag refers this?

Comment: @Spokey, I just added the rest of the code, it is in keyup, and I want the em to be inserted only ONCE, and next append the rest of the chars that exceed the maxLen, thanks a lot!

Comment: [something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/8Lkr4/)

Comment: @Spokey, I checked your jsfiddle that's not what I want to do. I will add more details to my post, wait.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/8Lkr4/2/

Comment: What is `.btn` referring to?

Comment: @Spokey I suggest using `next('em')` instead of classes, and create one it it returns no elements.

Comment: @ChristopherW, .btn is just a CSS class, it will disable/enable button based on the current counter.

Comment: @Broxzier How will next() work?

Comment: @Broxzier that may also work but it's not a must. [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/8Lkr4/4/)

Comment: Yup, but it's best practice not to use classes for every small thing.
jQuery next: http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: @Spokey, your jsfiddle the latest, just wraps the entire content inside em, this is what I already know how to achieve, but how to wrap or innerhtml after a certain length seems impossible right now, it worked just 10 minutes ago, now it doesn't :(

Comment: @Broxzier, what's wrong with my code? Is innerHtml() not supported? Weird, it worked just some 10 minutes ago.

Comment: @JohnSmith http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/8Lkr4/5/ ?

Comment: Oooh, now I get what you want. You want a countdown saying how many characters people have left to use! It wasn't clear to me. innerHTML is not a jQuery property, but one of the DOM element. If you use `this.innerHTML` it should work, but you're converting it to a jQuery object with `$(this)`.

Comment: @Broxzier, I already have that. What I want is to somehow append the characters that exceed the limit, when the counter reports -1, -2 and so one, these characters should somehow append between two <em></em> and these <em> tags should be kept inside the div[contenteditable].

Comment: @Spokey, your latest jsfiddle looks promising, but I cannot get it work with the above code, can you somehow make it work with the above code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JohnSmith what exactly is not working?

Comment: For example, it's not smooth, the test does not flow with the background, as it would with your last example in your last jsfiddle, in addition, it's not easy to maintain stable control, because if users are going to use it, they might want better control on: Ctrl+A+Del etc. But your last example looks somewhat promising, if you can get it to work with my jsfiddle sample, I'd be happy to see that and mark your post as answer, but only if it works the way I want it. Thanks a lot! Sad that other StackOverFlow folks are not replying here to help:(.

Comment: @Spokey I just retried my own previous solution, and backspace does not work pefectly either, which is another problem to address, currently I am waiting for somebody that knows how to get around these issues and provide a smooth experience. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will make the overflowing characters red. I use `text()` because this ignores the `em` tag within the div.

```
$(function () {
    $('div').keyup(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            text = $this.text(),
            maxlength = 20;

        if (text.length > maxlength) {
            var first = text.substring(0, maxlength),
                overflow = text.substring(maxlength, text.length);

            // this.innerHTML = first + '<em>' + overflow + '</em>';
            $this.text(first);

            // Now all there's left to do is force the caret at the end,
            // but that's pretty much code and would make this messy.
            // I'm sure you can google this. There's a link in my answer.
        }
    });
});
```

With this HTML

```
<div contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" id="342387257900146688">
    Type here.
</div>
```

Here's a live fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BaN7D/1/

However, if it exceeds the max length, `.html()` will force the cursor at the beginning. There are samples out there to place a cursor at the end of the div. Here's someone on SO that asked a question about it with a good answer: [Set cursor position on contentEditable <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div)

Comment: See this, jsfiddle.net/FP4nu/5

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.html()` instead off `innerHTML` and then append.

Comment: that only wraps it, unfortunately!