# Adding a span to a particular word in a contendEditable div?

Tags: javascript, css, loops, html, contenteditable

I have a div which is content editable, and  JS function to search the input for certain words. If a match is found, the content od the div turns blue, but I want **only** the matched word to turn blue. How can I do this? 
Here is my JS...

```
   function init() {

window.setInterval(function() {

    var div = document.getElementById("texty");
    var html = div.innerHTML;
    var buzzword = ["function","()","{", "}","[", "]",".getElementById", ".getElementsByClassName",".style","$"];

    for(var i = 0; i < buzzword.length; i++) 
    {
        var regex = new RegExp(buzzword[i], 'g');
        html = html.replace(regex, "<span style='color:blue'>" + buzzword[i] + "</span>");
    }

    div.innerHTML = html;

}, 100);


}
```

and my HTML is this...

`<div id="texty" contenteditable="true" onfocus="init()"></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the html of the div then do a regex replace and add a span around the word. Code would look something like this:

```
    var escape= function(s) {
        return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
    };

    var div = document.getElementById("texty");
    var html = div.innerHTML;
    var buzzword = ["function","()","{", "}","[", "]",".getElementById", ".getElementsByClassName",".style","$"];
    for(var i = 0; i < buzzword.length; i++)
    {
        var regex = new RegExp(escape(buzzword[i]), 'g');
        html = html.replace(regex, "<span style='color:blue'>" + buzzword[i] + "</span>");
    }

    div.innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: Thanks! This code looks good, but it's having no effect on my webpage. Any idea why? :S

Comment: There could be several reasons. Can't really tell you without looking at your page. Don't directly copy my code, but instead, look at what it does and tailor it to fit your needs.

Comment: I've edited my question to show my html, and my new JS using the code you showed me. I can't find any errors in it, atleast not spelling or syntax ones!

Comment: Accepted! :) Do you know why after the span is applied, my cursor is moved back to the beginning, and cannot be moved forward again? O.o

Comment: yes, but thats a very larger problem. Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div