# document.execCommand() with bootbox.js prompt

Tags: javascript

I'm using the [bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/) prompt  as the following :

```
document.getElementById('picture').addEventListener('click', function(){
    bootbox.prompt('URL de l\'image: ', function(result){
        document.execCommand('insertImage', false, result);
    });
}, false);
```

But this line `document.execCommand('insertImage', false, result);` seems that it doesn't work.

I tried to do an alert instead and it worked.

Why the `document.execCommand()` doesn't executed ? and how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, this is just more than I can fit in a comment.

The element that is set as `contenteditable="true"` has likely lost its focus ( or it's `contenteditable = true` is not set )

**Try**

```
document.getElementById('picture').addEventListener('click', function(){

    var editabletarget = document.getElementById("currentcontenteditableid");
    bootbox.prompt('URL de l\'image: ', function(result){
        /* reset editable and focus() */
        editabletarget.setAttribute("contentEditable", true);
        editabletarget.focus();

        document.execCommand('insertImage', false, result);
    });
}, false);
```

Replacing `currentcontenteditableid` with your current contenteditable element id.

Give that a try, hope works ( seems likely ). If not please give us

- a little more info on what bootbox.js is and what it is doing
- some of the html

Comment: Thanks it worked, but still there is a problem that the image is inserted in the start of the editable div.

Comment: I know! welcome to the fun world of contenteditable `cursor` recall! The answer to that is quite large, so best searching on it or posting a new question. Here is a good start - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div. The priciple is to store the cursor position before the click and then reset it after the focus before inserting the image.