# Keyboard cursor position goes at beginning when I set the text in jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, cursor-position

I am having 1 div and I have set conenteditable attribute to true.

Whenever I change the text of that div the cursor goes to beginning of the line.

```
var tmp = this.innerHTML;

this.innerHTML = tmp+"123";
```

I do not want the cursor position goes to beginning of the line.

Comment: where is the code for the cursor ? or have you written something like **.focus()** ??

Comment: I am new in javascript. How can I do this using focus()

Comment: can you show the full code ?? in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=mjDaxd9fpl

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div