# Why triggering click on contenteditable doesn't activate element and set cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want contenteditable to become active with cursor on the simulated click event, however this doesn't happen - the element doesn't get activated. Why? I need to put a cursor at exactly the same position as the user clicked, that's why I'm using `click` event since it contains coordinates.

I've created [this](https://jsfiddle.net/aL5Lyw56/) simple setup to demonstrate the problem (click inside the contenteditable div):

HTML

```
<div contenteditable="true" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black;">some text</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    var editable = $('[contenteditable]');
    var event, initial = true;
    editable.on('click', function(e) {
        event = e;
        console.log('writing event', event);

        if (initial) {
            initial = false;
            editable.blur();
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log('trigger click');
                editable.trigger(e);
            }, 3000);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking to trigger the `focus` event, which will place a cursor in the box and allow you to edit the content, without having to actually click inside the div. Is that what you were looking to do?

```js
$(function() {
  var editable = $('[contenteditable]');
  setTimeout(function() {
    editable.trigger('focus');
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black;">some text</div>
```

Comment: I need to put a cursor at exactly the same position as the user clicked, that's why I'm using `click` event since it contains coordinates.

Comment: Not sure if this answers the exact same question, but it may help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div?rq=1

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't answer this question, thanks for bothering to lookup

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm trying to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @PascalLindelauf, unfortunately no