# focus at mouse position in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a contenteditable element like this:

```
<p id="editor" contenteditable="true">Ok I am an element.</p>
```

How do I set the cursor in the element to wherever the mouse pointer is?

None of my attempted methods work:

```
$("#editor").click();
$("#editor").focus();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set cursor position on contentEditable <div>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div)

Comment: `focus` only focuses the div it cannot do that on containing text data