# Move view of clipped contenteditable div to cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following functions to allow a user to press a button that allows them to edit the contents of a `div`. By clicking a button `.rename` the `div` becomes editable and the contents are all selected, and the `text-overflow:ellipsis` is replaced with `text-overflow:clip`. When they finish editing, the user clicks enter and the `div` is no longer editable, and the `text-overflow:ellipsis` returns.

Everything is working, except that if the text is longer than the size of the `div`, the now not-editable `div` shows the text from the end, instead of from the beginning, even though I added additional code that moves the caret to the beginning of the text. Any thoughts on how I can move the view of the div to the location of the cursor/the beginning of the text?

Here's the code:

```js
//Makes tile contenteditable
$('.rename').click(
 function() {
  var renameThis = $(this).parent().parent().parent().children(':first'), range, selection;
  $(renameThis).attr('contenteditable','true').selectText();
  $(renameThis).css('text-overflow','clip');
  
 });

 //Makes the enter key close the tile editing
$('div.tile').keydown(function(e) {
    // trap the return key being pressed
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      // insert 2 br tags (if only one br tag is inserted the cursor won't go to the next line)
   var renameThis = this, range, selection;
  range = document.createRange();//Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
        range.selectNodeContents(renameThis);//Select the entire contents of the element with the range
        range.collapse(true);//collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
        selection = window.getSelection();//get the selection object (allows you to change selection)
        selection.removeAllRanges();//remove any selections already made
        selection.addRange(range);//make the range you have just created the visible selection
       $(renameThis).attr('contenteditable','false');
    $(renameThis).css('text-overflow','ellipsis');
       // prevent the default behaviour of return key pressed
       return false;
     }
  });

jQuery.fn.selectText = function(){
    this.find('input').each(function() {
        if($(this).prev().length == 0 || !$(this).prev().hasClass('p_copy')) { 
            $('<p class="p_copy" style="position: absolute; z-index: -1;"></p>').insertBefore($(this));
        }
        $(this).prev().html($(this).val());
    });
    var doc = document;
    var element = this[0];
    console.log(this, element);
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(element);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();        
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(element);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
};
```

```css
div.tile {
 width:100px;
 height:30px;
 background-color:#0C6;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width: 0px;
 border-color:#0C6;
 margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
 color:#FFF;
 padding-left:10px;
 line-height:30px;
 font-size:25px;
 cursor:pointer;
 /*border-radius: 5px;*/
 box-shadow: 0 3px #00994d;
 float:left;
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="tile webtile">Netflix</div>
  <div class="dropdown-this-content-container">
    <div class="dropdown-this-content"> 
      <div class="rename">Click here to rename</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS as well

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14022827/1035104

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. All I had to do was temporarily change the CSS of the div to `overflow:scroll`, set the scroll position to 0, then change back to `overflow:hidden` before changing back before finishing.