# Blinking cursor shifting at start of the text with onInput

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I'm handling text using `contentEditable` and `onInput` on `<div>`

```
<>
  <div
  contentEditable
  data-which="title"
  onClick={e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }}
  onInput={(e) => alter(e)}
  className={styles.widgetSignalTitleText}
 >
    {widget.alterations.title}
 </div>
</>
```

After I insert a text at the end of existing text, the blinking cursor is shifting to the start of the whole text.
How can this be prevented?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div/75514935#75514935 I have answered here. Hope that helps