# Javascript/jQuery : Refocus a contenteditable div that has child elements within

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, contenteditable, setfocus

**My Aim:** 
I am detecting hash tags within a content editable field as they are typed. I want to be able to remove a hash tag a it is typed, append it to another container and refocus selection on the contenteditable div as if nothing happened.

**My Problem:**
This works so long as there are no child elements within the contenteditable div but focus is not restored if there are children. I think I need an advanced method of focusing the caret. This has only been tested in Chrome so far.

**My Example:** http://jsbin.com/owoto4/5/edit

Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I may have cracked it by using code from this post:**
[contenteditable, set caret at the end of the text (cross-browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233265/contenteditable-set-caret-at-the-end-of-the-text-cross-browser)

See my example now: http://jsbin.com/owoto4/5/edit