# Limit the number of characters in a WYSIWYG Editor (NicEdit)

Tags: jquery, text, nicedit, keyup

I have this jQuery code:

```
var char = 60;
    $("#counter").append("You have <strong>" + char + "</strong> char.");
    $("#StatusEntry").keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length > char) {
            $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, char));
        }
        var rest = char - $(this).val().length;
        $("#counter").html("You have <strong>" + rest + "</strong> char.");
        if (rest <= 10) {
            $("#counter").css("color", "#ff7777");
        }
        else {
            $("#counter").css("color", "#111111");
        }
    });
```

It works fine!
But if instead a val() I have text() it doesn't work.

The problem is that at the end of available char it start to replace the text from the beginning...... using val is perfect.

Why I need it on text?
Because I'm using a wysiwyg plugin and it convert my textarea to div.

I'm trying with .stopPropagation but it doesn't work.. trying with return false and nothing...

Hope in your help!

Comment: Which line does it not work when you change val() to text() ... what doesnt work ? and can you please include your HTML ... i have no idea what statusentry is ...

Comment: if you change every val() to text() and you start typing, at 60 char it start to replace the text from begin.

Comment: like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/RjNuX/1/

Comment: Your substr was incorrect, works here -> http://jsfiddle.net/RjNuX/2/

Comment: yes exactly, if you use a wysiwyg plugin and if you don't have anymore a textarea but a <div> you need to use .text() to get values... and it doesn't work anymore...

Comment: More than likely the rich text editor is more than a simple div and has its own callback that you can use to achieve this. Which editor are you using?

Comment: text() wont work on a textarea as the text within it is stored as its value - can you tell us which WYSIWYG editor your using ?

Comment: Works fine for me using a div and contentEditable=true -> http://jsfiddle.net/RjNuX/3/

Comment: please insert an answer so I can close the question. Thanks.

Comment: you mean you dont need the WYSIWYG editor any more ? just a contentEditable div ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to use the NicEdit then you can limit the keystrokes by binding the keyup / keydown event to the newly created div (it doesnt replace your textarea - its adds a div and hides your textarea) :

```
$("#StatusEntry").prev().keydown(function () {
```

This works because the newly create div is always preceding the textarea - so this will work for multiple editors.

However as you seem to have indicated in your comments a contentEditable div may be sufficient - if it is use the following method :

```
    var char = 60;
    $("#counter").append("You have <strong>" + char + "</strong> char.");
    $("#StatusEntry").keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).text().length > char) {
            $(this).text($(this).text().substr(1));
        }
        var rest = char - $(this).text().length;
        $("#counter").html("You have <strong>" + rest + "</strong> char.");
        if (rest <= 10) {
            $("#counter").css("color", "#ff7777");
        }
        else {
            $("#counter").css("color", "#111111");
        }
    });
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/RjNuX/3

Comment: the solution you suggest works, but replacing the textarea with a div simply cancels the form submitting. (There is no textarea to submit). How could this be done without replacing textarea with a div?

Answer (score 0):

you have to target the nice edit div.

```
$(".nicEdit-main").keyup(...
```

If you have multiple editors, this solution will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var len = 40;    
$(".nicEdit-main").keydown(function () {
    if($(".nicEdit-main").html().length>len){
        var string = $('.nicEdit-main').html();
        $('.nicEdit-main').html(string.substring(0, len));
        placeCaretAtEnd($('.nicEdit-main').get(0));
    }
});
```

placeCaretAtEnd function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233265/contenteditable-set-caret-at-the-end-of-the-text-cross-browser/4238971#4238971)