# Moving cursor position in contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to move the cursor of a content editable div to the end of the line. By default, it goes to the beginning of the line.

I'm using:

```
var r = $("#mydiv").createTextRange(); 
r.moveStart("character", l); 
r.moveEnd("character", l);      
r.select();
```

The error I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'createTextRange'
```

I've seen this question posted around, but I still can't seem to perform createTextRange(). Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but does this answer the question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4238971/96100

Answer (score 0):

http://help.dottoro.com/ljouisvm.php

The createTextRange() method is no longer supported by most browsers.

You could replace that div with a styled textarea or place one inside of the div.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery plugin you can give a try.

A small cross-browser JavaScript library for obtaining and manipulating selections within  and  HTML elements.

http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/

Comment: Great though it is (disclaimer: I wrote it), that's for textareas and inputs, not contenteditable.