# Set Cursor position after nested contentEditable

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable, caret

I've got this markup

```
<div contentEditable="true">
    Some other editable content
    <div class="field" contentEditable="false">
        <span class="label">This is the label</span>
        <span class="value" contentEditable="true">This is where the caret is</span>
    </div>
    <!-- This is where I want the Caret -->
</div>
```

The caret is currently in the `.field` span.

I need to move it back out **after** the `.field` in the parent `contentEditable`.

[image: Example]

How can this be accomplished via javascript (with the use of jQuery if needed) ?

It will be trying to trigger it on a keydown event when the caret is in the .value span as shown.

Comment: *When* do you want to move it after `.field`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Whenever I want, via javascript... It will most likely end up on a `keydown` event when the caret is in the `.value` span.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's possible unless you have a non-empty node after the `.field` div

Comment: @ExplosionPills So couldn't I insert a non-empty div after the one that currently has focus, and then move it?

Comment: Yeah that should work fine, I just wasn't sure whether you wanted to do that.  Is your question more about how to move the cursor with JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An update to the previous answer.
http://jsfiddle.net/GLzKy/4/

```
placeCaretAtEnd($(this).parent().nextAll('.field').children('value'));
```

**UPDATE**

Updated answer with correct answer in comments

> For moving directly after the current field, you might want to use range.setStartAfter and range.setEndAfter: http://jsfiddle.net/GLzKy/5

Comment: Not quite what I'm after, if you read the comments in the HTML you'll see what I'm after.  Not to jump to the next field, but to move it directly after the current field.

Comment: For moving directly after the current field, you might want to use range.setStartAfter and range.setEndAfter: http://jsfiddle.net/GLzKy/5/

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you want to go to this next section. To make it clear, I added a text "Here!" in a demo to show you that it does goes to the end.

In the below demo, press <kbd>Enter key</kbd> from the `.field .value` to go to the end.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/GLzKy/1/

Below is the function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4238971/297641 which actually does all the work.

```
$('.field .value').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) { //Enter Key
        e.preventDefault();            
        placeCaretAtEnd($(this).closest('.parent')[0]);
    }
});

/**
  This below function is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4238971/297641
  All credits goes to the original author.
*/
function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
    el.focus();
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
            && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        range.collapse(false);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    }
}
```

**Tested in FF, IE8 and Chrome**

**Reference:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/4238971/297641

Comment: Close, but my modifications should explain the problem with this solution ... http://jsfiddle.net/GLzKy/3/ ... I needs to go to the next section immediately after the element with focus, not at the very end of the parent.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/farrukhsubhani/GLzKy/6/ added an alert to test and it seems to go to right place but if you remove alert then it does not. Something to play with at least if not final solution.

Comment: Works fine. Tested with chrome.