# Javascript/Jquery: How to set focus at id inside contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following html:

```
<div id="content" contenteditable="true" style="font-family: Helvetica;">
    Some text
    <div id="cursor" contenteditable="true"></div>
    Some other text.
</div>
```

Now I want to set cursor after Some text (exactly in `#cursor`). I tried both way:

```
$('#cursor').focus();
document.getElementById('#cursor').focus();
```

but it didn't work. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean when saying 'set cursor'?

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449721/set-cursor-position-after-nested-contenteditable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#content` is the outer editable element, so you'll need to focus that, and move the caret inside `#cursor`, but as `#cursor` has no content, there is nothing to target for a selection. A solution would be to add some content to target, like a textNode, move the caret, and then remove the content, like so:

```
var el    = document.getElementById("content"),
    el2   = document.getElementById("cursor"),
    range = document.createRange(),
    sel   = window.getSelection();

el2.innerHTML="temp";
var t = el2.childNodes[0];

range.setStartBefore(t);
range.collapse(true);
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
el.focus();
el2.innerHTML = "";
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/N5jwT/1/)

Comment: Doesnt work in Firefox, and Chrome does not get a blinking caret.