# How to programmatically start/stop editing a contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

What kind of event do I need to fire to programmatically start or stop actually editing a contenteditable, like when the user focuses or blurs it? I tried .focus(), .click(), [setting the selection to its content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4238971/90874), but none of them seem to work.

EDIT: .focus() does work, just make sure the contenteditable node is already inserted to the document...

Comment: you mean toggle the contenteditable attrib?

Comment: No, it is already contenteditable.

Comment: `keyup`, `keydown`, `keypress`?

Comment: What do you mean "start" or "stop" editing the element? The user is the one who starts or stops editing. Are you looking for an event to fire when they have done that?

Comment: When a user clicks in a contenteditable, a caret shows up and it responds to editing keyboard events. I want to activate this "editing mode" from JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `trigger()` method inside jQuery:

```
$('div[contenteditable="true"]').trigger('focus');
```

This will cause the caret to appear on page load, as per this [**jsFIddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8jTbY/1/).

Comment: Drat! Although I tried this, it didn't work because the contenteditable DOM node wasn't inserted into the DOM tree when I called .focus(). My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for **disabled** and **readonly** attributes.

```
HTML:
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />

Javascript:
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

other option is

```
HTML:
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" />

Javascript:
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
```