# How to pull contenteditable="true" cursor to the right

Tags: html, css

I am using this following code to make my header as editable text.

```
<h1 contentEditable="true">Hello</h1>
```

But it pulls the cursor in the beginning of the text, as in `|Hello`. I want it to be at right. Is there any way to do that? Specially Without javascript?

Comment: What are you going to do with the changed text without JS?

Comment: It depends. If you click between middle of the string it pulls the cursor on that place.

Comment: It's not possible without javascript.

Comment: @Rahil Wazir I think that he want it at the end, whatever the place that you click.

Comment: @Superdrac (_whatever the place that you click_) No he didn't mean that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that I know of to do this without javascript. The problem is that the browsers determine where to put the caret when the field is opened. However, if you choose to do a javascript solution, I would recommend looking [Tim Down's answer on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4238971/1789650). It works great!