# Positioning caret in JavaFX HTMLEditor

Tags: javascript, javafx

Having done next to none JavaScript before, I've tried several ways to position the caret (to end) in a JavaFX HTMLEditor without success.

For example, I've tried this: [contenteditable, set caret at the end of the text (cross-browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233265/contenteditable-set-caret-at-the-end-of-the-text-cross-browser) by adding the function `placeCaretAtEnd(el)` in the `<script>`-section, something like this (I omitted the `<script>` section here):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body onLoad='document.body.focus();' onfocus='placeCaretAtEnd(document.body);' contenteditable='true'>
</body>
</html>
```

(I set this via HTMLEditor.setHtmlText)

But the caret stays at the beginning.. has anyone successfully positioned the caret in a JavaFX HTMLEditor?

Comment: Where is the `placeCaretAtEnd` function defined?

Comment: Inside `<script></script>`, but I left it out in this example.

Comment: That `placeCaretAtEnd ` function does infact work but in your case I think you need to pass in the HTMLEditor element in order to place the caret at the end of it instead of the `document.body`

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it working finally. I'm not sure why the `onfocus` didn't work..

```
public void requestFocus() {
        HTMLEditorSkin skin = (HTMLEditorSkin) editor.getSkin();
        try {
            Field f = skin.getClass().getDeclaredField("webView");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            WebView wv = (WebView) f.get(skin);
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                wv.requestFocus();
                wv.getEngine().executeScript("document.body.focus()");
                wv.getEngine().executeScript(
                                "var el = document.body;\n" +
                                "if (typeof window.getSelection != \"undefined\"\n" +
                                "            && typeof document.createRange != \"undefined\") {\n" +
                                "        var range = document.createRange();\n" +
                                "        range.selectNodeContents(el);\n" +
                                "        range.collapse(false);\n" +
                                "        var sel = window.getSelection();\n" +
                                "        sel.removeAllRanges();\n" +
                                "        sel.addRange(range);\n" +
                                "    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != \"undefined\") {\n" +
                                "        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();\n" +
                                "        textRange.moveToElementText(el);\n" +
                                "        textRange.collapse(false);\n" +
                                "        textRange.select();\n" +
                                "    }");
            });
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```