# contentEditable set caret inside a particular element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unable to set caret into the first `<p>` in the contentEditable `<div>`.

I have seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4238971/586051) but its for before or after the element. How do I get it into an element?

Here is what I have so far:

```js
$('#content').on('click', function(){

  if($('#placeholder').length > 0)
    $('#placeholder').removeAttr('id').text('').focus();

});
```

```css
#content{
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
}

#placeholder{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='content' contentEditable=true>
  <p id='placeholder'>placeholder</p>
</div>
```

It clears the placeholder and doesnt set the caret at all.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you `p` element has no content and so has `0px` `height`. Watching the console you can see that `contenteditable` often add a `<br>` when clicking on it, you can do the same here and you'll have your caret.

```js
$('#content').on('click', function(){

  if($('#placeholder').length > 0)
    $('#placeholder').removeAttr('id').html('<br>').focus();

});
```

```css
#content{
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
}

#placeholder{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='content' contentEditable=true>
  <p id='placeholder'>placeholder</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you read any further please address to [Range (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Range) and [getSelection (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection).

This is a working **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0e5vwha0/2/).**

Code inside the fiddle is very self-explainatory, but what I found interesting was: let's say we have

```
<p id='paragraph'>I want to focus on this text</p>
```

then we do (as expected):

```
var p = $('#paragraph');
range.selectNode(p[0]);
```

This is actually going to put caret (roughly speaking) before `<p>`, but we need to get inside `<p>`.

**Surprisingly...**

```
var p = $('#paragraph');
var textInsideP = p.childNodes[0]; // the text inside p counts as a ChildNode
range.selectNode(textInsideP);
```

Boom.