# set the cursor at the end of the string?

Tags: javascript

When I replace a string with another, the cursor is moved to the beginning of the string in the text. Can the cursor be moved at the end instead of the start of the string?

**index.jsp**:

```
var val1=request.responseText;
var text=document.getElementById("para").innerHTML;
if(val1!="true")
{
    var afterplace=text.replace("good",val1);
    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML=afterplace;
}
```

After replacement the cursor come at the start of the word I want it at the end.

Comment: `para` is ID of what `input` or `div`? See http://jsfiddle.net/0mfk01h0/1/

Comment: div actually not paragraph

Comment: And where can you see cursor at DIV? Is there is any input?

Comment: no there isnot any input i made the div contenteditable n i want to replace some text n position of the cursor should be in the end

Comment: @kritikagoyal hey please provide html code with this

Comment: possible duplicate of [contenteditable, set caret at the end of the text (cross-browser)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233265/contenteditable-set-caret-at-the-end-of-the-text-cross-browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider following function for setting cursor at end of `contenteditable` element:

```
function setEndOfContenteditable(contentEditableElement)
{
    var range,selection;
    if(document.createRange)//Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE 9+
    {
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);
        range.collapse(false);
        selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
    else if(document.selection)//IE 8 and lower
    { 
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(contentEditableElement);
        range.collapse(false);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0mfk01h0/2/)

Full snippet:

```
var val1="testingtextgood";
var text=document.getElementById("para").innerHTML;
if(val1!="true")
{
    var afterplace=text.replace("good",val1);
    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML=afterplace;
    document.getElementById("para").focus()
    setEndOfContenteditable(document.getElementById("para"))
}

function setEndOfContenteditable(contentEditableElement)
{
    var range,selection;
    if(document.createRange)//Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE 9+
    {
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);
        range.collapse(false);
        selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
    else if(document.selection)//IE 8 and lower
    { 
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(contentEditableElement);
        range.collapse(false);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:-

```
var val1=request.responseText;
var text=document.getElementById("para").innerHTML;

if(val1!="true"){
    var afterplace=text.replace("good",val1);
    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML=afterplace;
    document.getElementById("para").focus();
    var val = document.getElementById("para").value;
    document.getElementById("para").value = '';
    document.getElementById("para").value = val;
}
```

It works fine for me.