# keyCode on android is always 229

Tags: javascript, android, html, keyevent

On my Samsung Galaxy tab 4 (Android 4.4.2, Chrome: 49.0.2623.105) I ran into a situation where the keyCode is always 229.

I've setup a simple test for two situation

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
<input>
<span id="keycode"></span>
```

script:

```
$('div, input').on('keydown', function (e) {
    $('#keycode').html(e.keyCode);
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ztu9d9j3/3/)

Fortunately I can find posts about this, but I couldn't find one with a working solution. Someone suggested to use `keyup` instead or to use the `textInput` event, but that one is only fired on `blur`.

Now, to top it all, this doesn't happen with the default stock browser :(

Any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE: If it turns out that this is not possible I can still grab the char before the caret: [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157435/get-last-character-before-caret-position-in-javascript)

Comment: I reproduced your issue in Chrome browser on a Samsung Galaxy S4. However it works fine in the stock browser.

Comment: sometimes, it is possible to listen for "beforeinput" event and use event.data property...

Comment: Bug still exists.  I'm running a chrome 112.0.5615.136 on an Android 13; Pixel 7 Pro device. Very unfortunate that this hasn't been fixed!  I've hacked in the 229 keycode for now.

Comment: All the tech companies should sit together and make some standards. This is insane.

Answer (score 33):

Normal keypress event does not give keyCode in android device. There has already been a big [discussion](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118639) on this.

If you want to capture the press of `space bar` or `special chars`, you can use `textInput` event.

```
$('input').on('textInput', e => {
     var keyCode = e.originalEvent.data.charCodeAt(0);
     // keyCode is ASCII of character entered.
})
```

Note: `textInput` does not get triggered on alphabets, number, backspace, enter and few other keys.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue and could not find any solutions.

```
event.target.value.charAt(event.target.selectionStart - 1).charCodeAt()
```

Comment: I don't think that would work if the cursor is anywhere before the last character and the character is being inserted.

Comment: Hey Thanks for pointing it out. I have fixed it and it should give char code based on cursor position

Comment: May I ask how you fixed it? Could you post the code? Thank you.

Comment: `event.target.selectionStart`  this line with get caret position

Comment: To get the most recent textInput value, I used this answer but updated the code to `event.originalEvent.data.charCodeAt(event.originalEvent.data.length - 1)`

Answer (score 7):

Running into the same problem, only happens with stock Samsung keyboard on Android. A work around was to turn off the keyboard predictions, which fixed the input. Still analysing further to see if a work around can be found in JS land.

**Edit:** I've managed to find a solution for our case. What was happening, is that we had a whitelist of allowed characters that a user was allowed to enter in our input box. These were alphanumeric characters plus some whitelisted control characters (e.g. enter, esc, up/down). Any other character input would have the event default prevented.

What happened is that all events with keycode 229 were being prevented, and as a result no text was entered. Once we added keycode 229 to the whitelist as well, everything went back to functioning ok.

So if you are using some kind of custom or 3rd party form input control component, make sure to check that keycode 229 is whitelisted/allowed and not default prevented.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I would be interested in a working solution, but I gave up and I'm now focussing on a solution in which I use the caret position and compare the string before the keypress and after. Note that this solution doesn't work very well for keys like SHIFT, CTRL, etc

Comment: This issue has also been seen on my Google Pixel using the Gboard

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue on Samsung S7 phones. Solved it by replacing event from keydown to **keypress**.

```
$("div, input").keypress(function (e) {
    $("#keycode").html(e.which); 
});
```

jQuery normalizes this stuff, so there's no need to use anything other than e.which https://stackoverflow.com/a/302161/259881

Comment: Tried this and the event never fired for me (panasonic toughpad).

Comment: document.onkeypress and window.onkeypress never fire on my android tablet

Comment: Return 229, too.

Comment: `keypress` is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to use [`onbeforeinput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/beforeinput_event) and [`oninput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) events along with their `.data` attribute to find the character values instead of `keydown` and `keyup` with `.key` and `.keycode`.

http://jsfiddle.net/vLga0fb9

https://caniuse.com/?search=beforeinput

Comment: It is wished to detect all keys, not only those which prints characters

Comment: The question is only about keycode=229, which is basically emitted for print characters. So one can use `onbeforeinput` and `oninput` to resolve those keys. Metakeys are already resolved by `keydown` etc. So to resolve all keys each event needs to be checked.

Comment: When there are 2 input fields on the page and enter is pressed, it doens't detect and go to other input. Please see here http://jsfiddle.net/3ocv97sd/3/

Comment: This was part of my solution, but one thing that stuck out was that `onbeforeinput` fired *after* `onkeydown`.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm answering an old post, but yet this problem is still ON so I like to share a view on it.
However this method is not an exact solution, but just a solution for urgency as I had. 
The key is to use the value of the textbox while using keypress. for every key press value will change and by the last value update we can make which key has been pressed.
***Note: this only works for the visible font on the keyboard, i.e., alphanumerics and special chars, this will not record any control or shift or alt keys as you know***

```
  $('input').keyup(function () {
  var keyChar = $(this).val().substr(-1);

 //you can do anything if you are looking to do something with the visible font characters
  });
```

Comment: What if the user has placed their caret somewhere other than the end of the string? You would need to use the inputs caret position, not just substring -1

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is still an issue on mobile so the only way to resolve it is to provide workarounds.
For the enter key you can do the following using oninput(event):

```
let lastData = null;
function handleInputEvent(inputEvent) {
    switch (inputEvent.inputType) {
        case "insertParagraph":
            // enter code here
            break;
        case "insertCompositionText":
            if (lastData === inputEvent.data) {
                // enter code here
            }
            break;
        case "insertText": // empty text insertion (insert a new line)
            if (!inputEvent.data) {
                // enter code here
            }
    }
    lastData = inputEvent.data;
};
```

To create other workarounds you can check out the docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent
and specs: https://w3c.github.io/input-events/#interface-InputEvent

A working example, just type in anything and press enter: https://jablazr.github.io/web-console/

Comment: `input` event listener will not get fired on pressing the `Enter` key, so why are you saying 
 *For the enter key you can do the following*?

Answer (score 1):

```
e.target.value.endsWith(',')
```

you can work with this. For `android` device.

something like

```
    $(document).on("keyup", '.tagsinput', function (e) {
        // console.log('|'+e.target.value.endsWith(',')+'|')
        // elif 

        if (e.keyCode == 188 || e.keyCode == 13 || e.target.value.endsWith(',')) { // KeyCode For comma is 188
            // alert('comma added');
            word = e.target.value.split(',')[0]
            console.log(word.length)
            if (word.length != 0) {
                console.log(word);
                tagsarray.push(word)
                e.target.value = ''
                tagarea.innerHTML += `<div class="block" id="${word}"><span class="tagscircle">${word}</span><div class="inline-block" attr-val="${word}" onclick="removeTag(event)"><svg attr-val="${word}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" role="img" width="1em" height="1em" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" d="M20 20L4 4m16 0L4 20"/></svg></div></div>`
                resultsBox1.innerHTML = ''
            }
            else {
                e.target.value = ''

            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that for the specific use-case of detecting the `enter` key, setting the input's `enterkeyhint` to `done` fixed this issue for the "enter" key. Once I did this, its key code was no longer 229, but rather the correct "enter" code.

Answer (score -1):

Solution to fix it for WebView, note it handles only space character , but you can extend mapping `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE => keyCode`.

```
class MyWebview: WebView {
    override fun onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs: EditorInfo): InputConnection? {
        return BaseInputConnection(this, true)
    }

    override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        val dispatchFirst = super.dispatchKeyEvent(event)

        // Android sends keycode 229 when space button is pressed(and other characters, except new line for example)
        // So we send SPACE CHARACTER(here we handles only this case) with keyCode = 32 to browser explicitly

        if (event?.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {
            if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                evaluateJavascript("javascript:keyDown(32)", null)
            } else if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                evaluateJavascript("javascript:keyUp(32)", null)
            }
        }

        return dispatchFirst
    }
}
```

Answer (score -12):

Try `e.which` instead of `e.keyCode`

For more information on this property check https://api.jquery.com/event.which/