# Keydown event not working in Android Device

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I write a function using keydown event to let an input only allow number, '-', and BackSpace key. When I test in ionic serve or iOS, it worked. But when I test in Android device, its not working, input field will allow all the character inputed.
When I use console.log (event), it always returns the key=“Unidentified”, keyCode = 229.

Environment: Ionic 3, Node v6.11, NPM 3.10, Android 5.1.1

I don't know how to fix this.

.ts file

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  isValidNumber(event) {
    //console.log(event);
    return /\d|-|Backspace/.test(event.key);

  }
}
```

.html file

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-item>
      <ion-input  type="text" (keydown)="isValidNumber($event)"></ion-input>
  </ion-item> 
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `type="number"`?

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa I want to input a string value like '0001234', so if type = number, it'll convert to 1234. Anyway, I want allow input '-' character, too. I updated my answer.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753548/keycode-on-android-is-always-229

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
function isValidNumber(e) {
if (
    !(e.keyCode === 8 || !(e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) ||  // 0-9
        !(e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105) // numpad 0-9
        // some more checking like arrows, delete, backspace, etc.
        || e.keyCode == 229)) { // Check for the 'placeholder keyCode'
    return false;
}
{
    // This is not a valid key
    e.preventDefault();
}
return true;
```

}

Found [here](https://gielberkers.com/what-is-keycode-229/)

Please read also the following: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2010JulSep/att-0182/keyCode-spec.html

Comment: all the character I input from Android keyboard always return keyCode = 229;

Comment: Im testing in a real android device, sir (samsung e5 SM-E500H).

Comment: What is the default language of the device? check my updated answer

Comment: default is Vietnamese, but I change to English(US), it still not work