# Angular 6 - Keydown Space on Mobile

Tags: html, angular, angular6, keyboard-events, keyevent

I have an `input` where I listen for the `keydown.space` event. This technique works fine on the desktop, but the event isn't triggered on mobile. My HTML template looks like the following:

```
<input
    type="text"
    (keydown.space)="onAdd()"
    (keydown.backspace)="onRemoveLast()"
>
```

So I need a way to listen to the `space key` event on the software keyboard of mobile phones.

Comment: you mean with a physical keyboard ?

Comment: Nope, the inbuilt software keyboard on phones

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keyCode on android is always 229](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753548/keycode-on-android-is-always-229)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What "mobile" did you test it on? If it's Android, like William Moore said, it may be an issue of Android not registering spacebar keypress as the standard 32.

Otherwise, you can try **onkeypress** + listening for the **keycode** on the JS side like so:

```
<input
  type="text"
  onkeypress="onAdd(event)"
  (keydown.backspace)="onRemoveLast()"
>

function onAdd(event){
  if (event.keyCode === 32) ...
}
```

Comment: thank you, it might actually be caused by the Android issue

Answer (score 0):

That's what I did to make it work:

HTML

```
<input
    [(ngModel)]="input"
    (keydown.backspace)="onRemoveLast()"
    (ngModelChange)="onChange()"
>
```

Typescript

```
public onChange(): void {
    if (this.input.substr(-1) === ' ') this.add();
}
```