# strange behaviour of Javascript handling of textbox input on Android devices

Tags: javascript, android, html, textbox

I am seeing strange behavior by Javascript on Android devices. I want an HTML textbox that behaves very like a password field - the characters are obscured as the user types. I have reduced the code to a single line. Works fine on my PC, on iPhone, and on iPad. But not my Moto phone or Samsung tablet, both of which are running Android.

```
  <input type='text' ID='txtPseudoPassword' name='txtPseudoPassword' onkeydown = 'if (event.keyCode != 8 && event.keyCode != 46) { document.getElementById("txtPseudoPassword").value += "#"; return false; } else return true; ' >
```

I have tried using `event.preventDefault();` as well as `return false;` but it makes no difference. I have tried onkeypress instead of onkeydown, but similarly, the devices that already work continue to do so and the Android devices don't.

So if I type 'ABC' into an iPad, I see '###'. If I type it into either of the Android devices at my disposal, I get '#A#AB#ABC'.

Another example might be helpful (at least in ruling out 'use a password field'). Take this line

```
<input type='text' ID='txtPseudoPassword' name='txtPseudoPassword' onkeydown = 'if (event.keyCode != 8 && event.keyCode != 46) { document.getElementById("txtPseudoPassword").value += String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) ; return false; } else return true; ' >
```

On non-Android, it doubles any character entered. On Android, well .. try it and see

Comment: Why not `input type="password"` then?

Comment: I nearly added "please don't suggest I use a password input, I have a reason for what I want to do" - darn

Comment: Care to share? The more we know about what you are trying to do, the more accurate help we can give.

Comment: Scott, please see edited version

Answer (score 0):

```
// change this
<input type="text" ...
// to this
<input type="password" ...
```

The password behavior is sometimes automated by detecting the string `password` in other input attributes, but it's safer and more cross-platform to directly precise it in the input type attribute.

Answer (score 0):

OK, just in case it helps anyone, the problem appears to be that Android doesn't handle the key strokes properly ([keyCode on android is always 229](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753548/keycode-on-android-is-always-229)), and the solution (hopefully) is to use a different type of control with the contenteditable attribute set. Something along these lines

```
<p contenteditable ID='pPseudoTextField' name='pPseudoTextField' style='border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; height:20px; width: 150px;' oninput = 'document.getElementById("hdnCounter").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("hdnCounter").value) + 1; document.getElementById("pPseudoTextField").innerHTML = "#".repeat(document.getElementById("hdnCounter").value)'></p>
```