# event.preventDefault() doesn't work with keyCode 229?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make an input field with only integers enabled but in **Android Chrome** keyboard I'm unable to prevent the user from entering '.' key. The keycode for '.' key is 229 and cancelable is also true which is required for event.preventDefault(). [image: Console.log output for . key mobile]

The code comes and calls e.preventDefault() but somehow it doesn't work only for mobile input field in **Chrome** only. **Firefox** and **iOS Safari** works well.

```js
function checkNumeric(e) {
  if ([46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
    // Allow: Ctrl+A
    (e.keyCode === 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
    // Allow: Ctrl+C
    (e.keyCode === 67 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
    // Allow: Ctrl+X
    (e.keyCode === 88 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
    // Allow: home, end, left, right
    (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
    // let it happen, don't do anything
    return
  }
  // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
  if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
}
```

```html
<input type='tel' onkeydown='checkNumeric(event)'>
```

Comment: This  answer may be what you're after https://stackoverflow.com/a/42552368/9433780

Comment: @slee423 No already tried this but this isn't the case for me. In my case the keycodes are different for all the events and are working except for this case where the code is reaching till event.preventDefault() but it doesn't seems to have any effect.

Comment: Check the following response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952686/how-to-make-html-input-tag-only-accept-numerical-values

Comment: check this it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753548/keycode-on-android-is-always-229/42552368#42552368

Comment: @Fadi.AM No already tried this but this isn't the case for me. In my case the keycodes are different for all the events and are working except for this case where the code is reaching till event.preventDefault() but it doesn't seems to have any effect.

Comment: @Saggio Vecchino this is not working you can try the same fiddle if you've an Android device.

Comment: Check this answer here,hope ir helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/3404022/7184888

Comment: After doing some research found this is a known issue with Chrome. Anyone looking for details can find them here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=228440

Answer (score 0):

What if you change the conditions placements

```js
function checkNumeric(e) {
     // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
  if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
  if ([46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
    // Allow: Ctrl+A
    (e.keyCode === 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
    // Allow: Ctrl+C
    (e.keyCode === 67 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
    // Allow: Ctrl+X
    (e.keyCode === 88 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
    // Allow: home, end, left, right
    (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
    // let it happen, don't do anything
    return
  }
 
}
```

```html
<input type='tel' onkeydown='checkNumeric(event)'>
```

Comment: Doesn't matter on Android Chrome Keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Try to work around it, by playing with the event triggers. Just add the event `oninput` which will be triggered when the input change and after that you can just delete the last character if it's the `.` you're talking about and update the value of your input.