# Trying to prevent input into textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to prevent user input into a textarea with Javascript.

Why doesn't this work?

```
$("textarea").on("input", function (e) {
  console.log("returning"); //This prints
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
  //Even though this code runs when text is inputed into the textarea, it still doesn't prevent user input. Shouldn't returning false do that?
});
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298064/preventdefault-not-working-in-on-input-function

Comment: Try `keydown` instead of input

Comment: The input event fires _after_ there has been input to a control.  Quoting from https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Events/input _ -- "The DOM input event is fired synchronously when the value of an <input>, <select>, or <textarea> element is changed."_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.preventDefault() not working in on.('input', function{})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298064/preventdefault-not-working-in-on-input-function)

Answer (score 1):

You are preventing the default action of a noncancelable event, not the input. You need to disable the input to get the desired result, disable the input programatically:

```
$("textarea").prop("disabled", (1 === 2)/*some condition*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

> **[Input Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)** : The DOM input event is fired synchronously when the value of an `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` element is changed.

Use `keydown` instead of `input` for this purpose :

```js
$('textarea').keydown(function(e) {
  console.log("returning"); //This prints
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Is that doesn't answer you OP @Wyatt ?!

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want a cursor to even appear over your Element, then you should not use a textarea or input at all, but if you must, you can do this:

```
<textarea readonly='readonly'></textarea>
```

or

```
$('textarea').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```