# Why doesn't preventDefault() of an input event stop changes to the value of a form element

Tags: javascript, event-handling, textinput, sanitization, preventdefault

This question has been asked and answered before; none of the previous answers given here seem to fix my situation. Therefore I need to ask, once again, why isn't the event prevented correctly?

```
document.addEventListener("input", event => {
   if(event.data == '#' || event.data == '+' || event.data == '.' || event.data == ';'){
       event.preventDefault();
       alert("Non-allowed character detected: " + event.data);
       return false;
    }
});
```

I have tried different versions, for example I added the `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` but nothing changed. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

It might help to know that I'm simply trying to stop the input of certain characters.

Comment: If you want to prevent characters, you're better off defining a regex to validate the form element with. `input` events are fired *after* something was changed. Moreover, preventing certain characters is much less user-friendly than validating.

Comment: Consider using `keydown` if you wish to prevent text input?

Comment: Include enough code, preferably in the form of a snippet, that your issue can be reproduced.

Comment: @Ouroborus this is enough code to reproduce it. All the information needed is already in the question. Input events are very well documented, so the behaviour can be understood without needing runnable code.

Comment: @VLAZ There's no html. Documented or not, questions need to include everything needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Ouroborus input events fire *after* a change, not before. It's perfectly clear why preventing the default action of the event won't prevent the change *that already happened*

Comment: @VLAZ Doesn't matter. Include all the parts necessary to reproduce the question. Running just the provided code doesn't allow you to reproduce the issue. (You'd have to make assumptions to make it work. For example, you're assuming they're using an input element at all. Yes, silly, but it has happened.)

Comment: @Ouroborus Conceptual questions are perfectly on-topic. This is answerable as one.

Comment: @VLAZ This isn't a conceptual problem. The asker has code they're debugging.

Comment: @Ouroborus refer to the documentation of the input event. All the information in order to answer the question as asked is there.

Comment: @VLAZ Everything needed to reproduce the problem needs to be included in the question.

Comment: @Ouroborus I see just talk, no actions. Therefore, I can only conclude you don't truly believe this. I see no sense in continuing here.

Comment: @VLAZ The action was: requesting the additional code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.preventDefault() not working in on.('input', function{})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298064/preventdefault-not-working-in-on-input-function)

Comment: @Thegreen ... are you aware that there are solutions which do exactly what was ask for (_"It might help to know that I'm simply trying to stop the input of certain characters."_) with a single element-specific input-type handler-function and 7 lines of code instead of 3 document wide listeners (`keydown`, `drop`, `paste`) plus the element-specific `input` listener which altogether make a solution overly complex and at least triple the actually needed amount of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not prevent input because you are using an `"input"` event. The event listener `"input"` is fired after the input occurs, so its default cannot be prevented.

Instead, use `"keydown"` which fires before the action, hence the default action can be prevented.

Here is your updated code:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
    if (event.key === '#' || event.key === '+' || event.key === '.' || event.key === ';') {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Non-allowed character detected: " + event.key);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Also, if you want to stop someone from pasting in such characters using the `context menu` or `drag&drop`, you can use all these functions together:

```
// Existing code for detecting keystrokes
 document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
     if (event.key === '#' || event.key === '+' || event.key === '.' || event.key === ';') {
         event.preventDefault();
         alert("Non-allowed character detected: " + event.key);
         return false;
     }
 });

// Code to prevent pasting non-allowed characters
document.addEventListener("paste", event => {
    var clipboardData = event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData;
    var pastedData = clipboardData.getData('text');
    if (pastedData.includes('#') || pastedData.includes('+') || pastedData.includes('.') || pastedData.includes(';')) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Non-allowed character detected in your paste: " + pastedData);
        return false;
    }
});

// Code to prevent drop non-allowed characters
document.addEventListener("drop", event => {
    var droppedData = event.dataTransfer.getData('text');
    if (droppedData.includes('#') || droppedData.includes('+') || droppedData.includes('.') || droppedData.includes(';')) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Non-allowed character detected in your drop: " + droppedData);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Or if you really want to use `input`, you can, but first the content will be written, then deleted from the input:

```
// Listen to input event
inputField.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
    var value = event.target.value;
    // Check for disallowed characters
    if (value.includes('#') || value.includes('+') || value.includes('.') 
    || value.includes(';')) {
        alert("Non-allowed character detected.");
        // Remove disallowed characters
        event.target.value = value.replace(/[\#\+\.;]/g, '');
    }
});
```

All relevant parts of the above code as executable stack snippet ...

```js
// Existing code for detecting keystrokes
document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  if (event.key === '#' || event.key === '+' || event.key === '.' || event.key === ';') {
    event.preventDefault();

    alert("Non-allowed character detected: " + event.key);
    return false;
  }
});

// Code to prevent pasting non-allowed characters
document.addEventListener("paste", event => {
  var clipboardData = event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData;
  var pastedData = clipboardData.getData('text');

  if (pastedData.includes('#') || pastedData.includes('+') || pastedData.includes('.') || pastedData.includes(';')) {
    event.preventDefault();

    alert("Non-allowed character detected in your paste: " + pastedData);
    return false;
  }
});

// Code to prevent drop non-allowed characters
document.addEventListener("drop", event => {
  var droppedData = event.dataTransfer.getData('text');

  if (droppedData.includes('#') || droppedData.includes('+') || droppedData.includes('.') || droppedData.includes(';')) {
    event.preventDefault();

    alert("Non-allowed character detected in your drop: " + droppedData);
    return false;
  }
});

// Listen to input event
document.querySelector('input[type="text"]').addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  var value = event.target.value;

  // Check for disallowed characters
  if (value.includes('#') || value.includes('+') || value.includes('.') || value.includes(';')) {
    alert("Non-allowed character detected.");

    // Remove disallowed characters
    event.target.value = value.replace(/[\#\+\.;]/g, '');
  }
});
```

```css
form { width: 80%; }
label > span { display: block; margin: 4px 0 8px 0; }
input { width: 99%; }
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>+++ Some ... Text ... To ... Copy ... From +++</legend>

    <label>
      <span># more text to copy from; #</span>
      <input
        type="text"
        required
        pattern="[^#+.;]+"
        placeholder="following chars are not allowed ... #+.;"
      />
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: _"which does not have the `preventDefault()` method"_ - this isn't true. `input` inherits from [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)

Comment: I think what he means is that `preventDefault` has no meaning in this situation. It does technically exist, but its implementation does not do anything.

Comment: You're both correct, i fixed it, thanks friends!

Comment: By the way this still won't stop someone from pasting in such characters using the context menu or drag&drop, for example. Noteworthy to point out.

Comment: Fixed again, thanks friend!

Comment: Be aware that [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event) is deprecated.

Comment: Fixed again ahahahha, thanks friend!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily the answer you are looking for, but you can do the same with the help of RegEx. Use `match` to find out if the input has the restricted characters and if yes, remove it with help of `replace`.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('inp');
input.addEventListener("input", event => {
  if (input.value.match(/[#+.;]/g)){
  alert("Non-allowed character detected: " + input.value.match(/[#+.;]/g));}
  input.value = input.value.replace(/[#+.;]/g, '');
});
```

```html
<input id="inp" type='text'>
```

Comment: Do not nest if-statement. You could simply use `if (event.data?.match(/[+#;.]/g))`

Comment: The above implementation does not prevent pasting of invalid characters.

Comment: Pasting too works fine now.

Comment: @Akshay ... Regarding _"Pasting too works fine now"_ ... it does, but the caret position does not get preserved. It always gets placed at the end of the current input data which means the caret unexpectedly jumps from the place the insert did happen e.g beginning or middle of the input string to its very end.

Answer (score 0):

As Kobra mentioned, you will need to capture the key during the `keydown` event.

I modified their response below; particularity decoupling the key check from the event handler.

```js
const DISALLOWED_KEYS = new Set(['#', '+', '.', ';']);

const disallowedList = document.querySelector('#disallowed');

renderKeys(disallowedList, DISALLOWED_KEYS);

document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
document.addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
document.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop);

function handleKeyDown(event) {
  if (isKey(event.key)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.error("Disallowed character detected: " + event.key);
    activateKey(event.key);
    return false;
  }
}

function handlePaste(event) {
  const clipboardData = getClipboardData(event);
  const pastedData = clipboardData.getData('text');
  if (containsKey(pastedData)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.error("Disallowed character detected in paste: " + pastedData);
    return false;
  }
}

function handleDrop(event) {
  const droppedData = event.dataTransfer.getData('text');
  if (containsKey(droppedData)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.error("Disallowed character detected in drop: " + droppedData);
    return false;
  }
}

function renderKeys(el, keys) {
  for (let key of [...keys].sort()) {
    el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
      <li>
        <kbd data-key="${key}">${key}</kbd>
      </li>
    `);
  }
}

function activateKey(key) {
  const kbd = disallowedList.querySelector(`kbd[data-key="${key}"]`);
  kbd.classList.add('active');
  setTimeout(() => { kbd.classList.remove('active'); }, 100);
}

const isKey = (s) => DISALLOWED_KEYS.has(event.key);
const containsKey = (s) => DISALLOWED_KEYS.values().some(k => s.includes(k));

function getClipboardData(event) {
  return event.clipboardData ||
         window.clipboardData || 
         event.originalEvent?.clipboardData;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 4rem !important;
}

ul#disallowed {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

ul#disallowed li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

kbd {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 1rem;
  border: 0.25rem solid grey;
  border-top-width: 0.125rem;
  padding: 0.125rem;
  font-family: monospace;
}

kbd.active {
  background: darkgrey;
  border-color: yellow;
  border: 0.25rem solid black;
  border-bottom-width: 0.125rem;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Something (except [#+.;])">
<hr>
<h2>Disallowed Keys</h2>
<ul id="disallowed"></ul>
```

Comment: The above provided code throws upon pasting (copy/paste and drag/drop) data either of valid or of invalid content.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the OP ...

> ... why isn't the event prevented correctly?

The input already happened, it's too late to prevent the changes which came along with it.

> It might help to know that I'm simply trying to stop the input of certain characters.

In order to achieves the OP's actual goal, a solution which omits such data for any kind of user input, needs to implement an immediate auto correction which also adapts the input element's caret position according to the user's most recent input action ...

```js
document
  .querySelector('input[type="text"]')
  .addEventListener('input', ({ currentTarget }) => {
    const { value, selectionEnd } = currentTarget;

    // - replace any occurrence of a non allowed character.
    const sanitizedValue = value.replace(/[#+.;]+/g, '');

    // - always replace the current value with its
    //   sanitized variant regardless of changes.
    currentTarget.value = sanitizedValue;

    // - determine whether the current value and 
    //   its sanitized variant are of same length.
    const deltaLength = value.length - sanitizedValue.length;

    // - in case of a changed text content length ...
    if (deltaLength != 0) {
      
      // ... adapt the caret position accordingly in order to
      //     not interfere with the user's experience/expectation.
      const caretPosition =
        Math.max(0, Math.min(sanitizedValue.length, selectionEnd - deltaLength));

      currentTarget.selectionStart = currentTarget.selectionEnd = caretPosition;
    }
  });
```

```css
form { width: 80%; }
label > span { display: block; margin: 4px 0 8px 0; }
input { width: 99%; }
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>+++ Some ... Text ... To ... Copy ... From +++</legend>

    <label>
      <span>### Auto Correction Input Field ###</span>
      <input
        type="text"
        required
        pattern="[^#+.;]+"
        placeholder="following chars are not allowed ... #+.; ... auto correction will take place."
      />
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```