# Need a normal cursor into a div when click on it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have prepared a Fiddle, please look into this.

https://jsfiddle.net/s7fxy8jp/

From the fiddle, would it be possible to blink normal cursor at the end of the text **Element Z (script-only focusable)** instead of a background color aqua.

HTML

```
<div tabindex="-1" id="scripted">Element Z (script-only focusable)</div>
<div id="test">Set Focus To Element Z</div>
```

CSS

```
div:focus {
background-color: Aqua;}
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('test').onclick = function () {
document.getElementById('scripted').focus();};
```

Comment: make it editable div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow your div content to be edited, by using the `contenteditable` property.

```
<div tabindex="-1" id="scripted" contenteditable="true">Element Z (script-only focusable)</div>
<div id="test">Set Focus To Element Z</div>
```

This will get you a blinking cursor on click. Unfortunately it is placed at the beginning of the line. You can solve this problem by [following the instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233265/contenteditable-set-caret-at-the-end-of-the-text-cross-browser).

Here's your [Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s7fxy8jp/1/)

Comment: Wow!!! Great thank you very much. Your solution works for me. One more request , is there any solution to identify <a> tag range instead of text range so that when I click on "Set Focus To Element Z", the cursor will blink on just after the end of all <a> tag. I have updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s7fxy8jp/8/

Answer (score 0):

I updated your JavaScript function to activate attribute contenteditable, then move caret to end of text. The text can only be edited when it is focus from "Set focus to element Z", otherwise, it is still a normal div. Note that I used jQuery for faster manipulation, the solution can still be implemented using pure JavaScript

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('test').onclick = function () {
    var char, sel,
        $div = $('#scripted'),
        div = $('#scripted')[0];
    $div.attr('contenteditable', 'true');
    $div.focus().blur(function() {
        $div.attr('contenteditable', 'false')
    });
        char = $div.html().length; // character at which to place caret  content.focus();
    sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.collapse(div.firstChild, char);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Html**

```
<div tabindex="-1" id="scripted" class="sj">Element Z (script-only focusable)</div>
<div id="test">Set Focus To Element Z</div>
```

**Css :**

```
.sj:hover {background: yellow;}
```