# Cast contenteditable div in order to access selectionEnd property

Tags: angular, typescript, casting

I have a `div` element with `contenteditable` attribute set to true.
the div has a 2 way binding to an angular class property.

the problem is when the text is changing via `(input)` event
the cursor looses focus and the user have a bad UX while trying to edit the text inside the div.

basically i am trying to achive something like that (js):

```
divlft.focus();
divlft.selectionEnd = end;
```

but if i try to cast the div to `HTMLInputElement` i get `undefined` value:

```
let txtlft = document.getElementById("divlft") as HTMLInputElement;
console.log(txtlft.selectionEnd); // delete
```

and if i try to cast the element to `HTMLElement`, clearly i can not access 
`selectionEnd` property

**Html:**

```
   <div class="txtAr txtleft" id="divlft"  contenteditable="true" [innerHTML]="LeftText | sanitizeHtml" (input)="textChanged($event.target.innerHTML)">


    </div>
```

**type script textChange method:**

```
public textChanged(value: string): void {
    let txtlft = document.getElementById("divlft") as HTMLInputElement;
    console.log(txtlft.selectionEnd); // delete
    this.LeftText = value;
    this.LeftText = "<span style='color: white;'>" + this.LeftText + "</span>";
    txtlft.focus();
    console.log(txtlft.selectionEnd)
}
```

I am very new to front end web development, so maybe i am missing something 
basic but i did not succeed to search a solution for that.

How can i approach this problem?

Comment: I don't know why casting fails, never used that though. But you may check the "placeCaretAtEnd" method in this answer; https://stackoverflow.com/a/4238971/3928819 It uses the range & selection APIs.

Comment: @cdagli, thank you for the link, that is exactly what i am trying to do now.