# how to make make conteneditable div do tab spacing when i hit tab key

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I tried to make this conteneditable div do tab spacing when i hit tab key but it does'n work. i hope someone have solutions for this problem. you can add id or class or anything you need to make it works. thanks

```css
div[contenteditable]{
  display:inline-block;
  font-family:lucida console;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:14px;
  white-space: pre;
  padding:5px;
  margin:0;
  min-width:200px;
  min-height:50px;
  height:auto;
  background:#fff;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">dwdw wdw</div>
```

Comment: Add a keyboard event listener (`keydown` / `keyup`). Whenever the Tab key is pressed check if the contenteditable div is focussed. If it is add multiple spaces to your div's `textContent`.

Answer (score 1):

you can create `keydown` event

i've seen a function to place the caret the end of the text whenever the the tab key is press. this runs on multiple browsers

check it out : [contenteditable, set caret at the end of the text (cross-browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233265/contenteditable-set-caret-at-the-end-of-the-text-cross-browser)

```js
$('#test').on( 'keydown', function( e ) {
    if( e.which == 9 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).html($(this).html() + "   ") 
        placeCaretAtEnd( document.querySelector('#test') );
    }
} );


function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
    el.focus();
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
            && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        range.collapse(false);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    }
}
```

```css
div[contenteditable]{
  display:inline-block;
  font-family:lucida console;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:14px;
  white-space: pre;
  padding:5px;
  margin:0;
  min-width:200px;
  min-height:50px;
  height:auto;
  background:#fff;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="test">asdfsadf</div>
```

Comment: you could upvote or mark answer if this solves your issue. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

use code as below

```js
function keypress(ev){
 if(ev.keyCode==9){
   ev.target.innerHTML+=" " ;
   ev.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```css
div[contenteditable]{
  display:inline-block;
  font-family:lucida console;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:14px;
  white-space: pre;
  padding:5px;
  margin:0;
  min-width:200px;
  min-height:50px;
  height:auto;
  background:#fff;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" onkeydown="keypress(event)">dwdw wdw</div>
```

Comment: Still not working bro. i am using chrome latest version.

Comment: Note: [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) is now deprecated. (was in answer pre-edit)

Comment: @לבנימלכה can you check your snippet before posting?   Your code adds a space at the end and moves the input caret - this is not "*do tab spacing*" as in the question (it *is* how to identify the tab key)

Comment: @לבנימלכה: that was exactly what I mean. But, space and the wrong caret position are fine. Thanks for helping me. I have 50% answer.  I'll take care of the rest.

Comment: here is solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249095