# Move cursor to end of contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to move cursor to end of contenteditable entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125292/how-to-move-cursor-to-end-of-contenteditable-entity)

How do I move the cursor to the end of a contenteditable div? I only need a solution that works in webkit, I dont care about ie or ff here.
The shorter, the better. :-)

Comment: Yes, but the accepted answer doesn't work for contenteditable divs, which is what my question is about

Comment: Welcome to SO @Leticia.  Does the second answer for the above Q answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125292/how-to-move-cursor-to-end-of-contenteditable-entity/3866442#3866442

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first answer you looked at will work for a textarea, but not for a contenteditable element.

This solution is for moving the caret to the end of a contenteditable element.

[How to move cursor to end of contenteditable entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125292/how-to-move-cursor-to-end-of-contenteditable-entity/3866442#3866442)