# How can I trigger a KeyboardEvent (DOM_VK_UP) that is actually handled by the browser, exactly as if the user typed the key?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following sample code, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/832121/391161).

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(this).ready( function() {
    $("#foobar").keydown(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode != KeyEvent.DOM_VK_UP) {
        console.log("Foo Bar");
        var f = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        f.which = KeyEvent.DOM_VK_UP;
        f.keyCode = KeyEvent.DOM_VK_UP; 
        $("#foobar").trigger(f);
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      }
      else {
        console.log("Hello World");
      }
    });
})
</script>
<div id="foobar" contenteditable="true"> 
  Foo Bar
  <br>
  Bar Bar
</div>
</body>
```

The output of this example is that the following is printed to the console very time a key is pressed. However, only when the real `Up` is pressed, does the cursor move up.

```
Foo Bar
Hello World
```

This implies that the trigger worked, *but the cursor does not move up*.

**How can I make the cursor behave exactly as if the user had pressed the `Up` key on his keyboard when any key is pressed, not just a real `Up`?**

I also tried the following way of triggering, which was also unsuccessful, despite printing `true` for success.

```
 var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");                     
 evt.initKeyEvent ("keypress", true, true, window,                    
 0, 0, 0, 0, KeyEvent.DOM_VK_UP, KeyEvent.DOM_VK_UP);                 
 var success = document.getElementById("foobar").dispatchEvent(evt)   
 console.log(success)
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make the key a appear in the div when any key is pressed,
>   not just a real a?

Try substituting `KeyboardEvent` for `KeyEvent` , utilizing `.html(function(index, html))`

```html
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(this).ready( function() {
    $("#foobar").keydown(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode != KeyboardEvent.DOM_VK_A) {
        console.log("Foo Bar");
        var f = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        f.which = KeyboardEvent.DOM_VK_A;
        f.keyCode = KeyboardEvent.DOM_VK_A; 
        $("#foobar").html(function(_, html) {
          return html + "a"
        }).trigger(f);
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      }
      else {
        console.log("Hello World");
      }
    });
})
</script>
<div id="foobar" contenteditable="true"> 
  Foo Bar
  <br>
  Bar Bar
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This works around the problem rather than solving it, unfortunately. I'll update my question, sorry.

Comment: @merlin2011 _"I get exactly the same behavior. Also, the values are the same."_ Does `js` at stacksnippets return expected result ? Not certain about requirement ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to actually simulate the event, because I'm trying to simulate `DOM_VK_UP` rather than an ascii character. I'm effectively trying to mimic a user pushing a key, rather than manually appending the key to the div. I originally used `a` in the question because I hoped it would be more clear.

Comment: @merlin2011 _"trying to actually simulate the event, because I'm trying to simulate DOM_VK_UP rather than an ascii character. I'm effectively trying to mimic a user pushing a key, rather than manually appending the key to the div."_ Is requirement to trigger a custom event ? Still not certain about expected result ?

Comment: I updated the question. Please let me know if it's still not clear. I am trying to move the cursor up, to simulate what happens when the user pushes `Up` on the keyboard.

Comment: @merlin2011 See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778291/move-the-cursor-position-with-javascript

Comment: That looks helpful for cursor movement specifically, but doesn't address the main question of whether it's possible to simulate a KeyboardEvent *exactly as if a user typed it.*