# Javascript - Move caret backwards when I click on contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, move, caret

I have got a contentEditable div and I want to move caret one field backwards after I click on this div. How can I do this?

This is my code. I want to do something to move caret between A and B when I click between B and C

```html
<div id="MainBox" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
    ABC
</div>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Show your code also, till how much you did.

Comment: As per my understanding, you want to move cursor one place forward right??

Comment: Yes, but I want to move cursor one place backward

Comment: You could have a look at this thread. It is some what close to what you want. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10782169/5909393

Comment: Thanks. Maybe this will help me.