# Move caret to the end in contenteditable element and alight text to the end

Tags: javascript

In my example i have 2 problems.

1.In the first click, the cursor not moved to the end.

2.In overflow, i need to alight text to the end, because there is free content input.

```js
$("a").click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var textBox = document.querySelector(".c_textBox")
  textBox.innerText += " hello  a,";
  var len = textBox.innerText.length + 1

  var range = document.createRange();
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  range.setStart(textBox.childNodes[0], len);
  range.collapse(true);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
  textBox.focus();
});
```

```css
.c_textBox {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  border: none;
  padding-right: 3rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 2rem;
  /* background-position: 100% 50%;*/
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: 2px black solid;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">add item</a><br/>
<div contenteditable="true" type='text' id="searchInput" class="c_textBox"> </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x3pf4nu2/

Comment: `var len = textBox.innerText.length + 2` will move the cursor to the end of the input.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/10782169

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `\u00a0` as an white space. Just like this:

```
$("a").click(function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  var textBox = document.querySelector(".c_textBox")
  textBox.innerText +="\u00a0hello\u00a0\u00a0a,";
  var len = textBox.innerText.length
  textBox.scrollLeft += textBox.innerText.length;
  var range = document.createRange();
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  range.setStart(textBox.childNodes[0], len );
  range.collapse(true);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
  textBox.focus();
});
```

And CSS:

```
.c_textBox{
  display:block;
  width:200px;
  height:40px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color:lightgrey;
  border: 2px black solid;
  padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but did you know a way to move the text to the and, that I could see the caret?

Comment: If you add new item you would like move cursor to the right and show scrollbar?

Comment: I wont the same behavior as when you just put some text, the text need to move left.

Comment: Try now, I hope that helps you :)

Comment: I'd change the overflow-x to auto instead of scroll.