# How to force the cursor to the beginning of an input value in React?

Tags: reactjs, validation, input

I'm essentially trying to emulate the Apple ID account creation birthday input (can be found here: https://appleid.apple.com/account or if you google Apple ID and click "Create Your Apple ID" on top).

Part of the functionality of the input is that when you click into it, if there's no current value it will default to `mm/dd/yyyy` and force the user's input caret to the front of the input, replacing characters from the front as the user types. Any later clicks in the input will force the user's cursor to after the spot in the value they've typed. E.g. `05/4m/yyyy` the cursor must be after the 4.

I've done a lot of searching and not came across any reliable ways to do this in React. Attempts to use `setSelectionRange` haven't worked. Thank you!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a placeholder... Or just an element behind the input?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778291/move-the-cursor-position-with-javascript) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div)?

Comment: It's masking, it's very common - something like this has the functionality you're looking for: https://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/