# HTML5 Content Editable paragraph after list

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, contenteditable, html-editor

I use Google Chrome.

I need to have a very tiny HTML editor and I found [Simple Edit](https://github.com/mlabod/simple-edit). Very small editor, just for my needs. However... This and many other editors that are using Content Editable have one common problem.

**Problem**

After creating a list (hit enter twice on last list item), it creates a new div. Expected to me would be to create a new paragraph tag.

**Links**

- **Try the editor here:** http://files.inlovewithcss.com/simple-edit/
- **Look at the tiny source code:** https://github.com/mlabod/simple-edit/blob/master/editor.jquery.js

**Question**

What is the correct way of prevent divs, and instead add paragraph tags after a list?

Comment: This will post a problem you know. If you replace your container element with paragraph tags instead of divs, successive lists will be children of paragraphs which, is invalid html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer posted by Bryan Allo did not take into account that you need to place the cursor at the end of the div. Otherwise upon every replace action the user would have to hit CTRL-End.

This is the solution I propose, also to be seen in action at http://jsfiddle.net/82dS6/:

```
function setEndOfContenteditable(contentEditableElement){
    // Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/3866442/1601088
    var range,selection;
    if(document.createRange){//Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE 9+
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);
        range.collapse(false);
        selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
    else if(document.selection){//IE 8 and lower
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(contentEditableElement);
        range.collapse(false);
        range.select();
    }
}

function replaceDivWithP(el){

    $(el).find('div').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($('<p>' + $(this).html() + '</p>'));
    });
}

$(function(){
    $(".text").simpleEdit();
});

$('.textarea').bind('keyup', function(){
    replaceDivWithP(this);
    setEndOfContenteditable(this);
});


​
```

Comment: This solution is the best one so far. Vote up so far. However when I click the list icon it add the list inside a paragraph.

Comment: It seems like there is no easy way around this because the library you're using uses ExecCommand to replace the contents which is not easy to hook into.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of processing on-the-fly with every `keyup` event, you could consider post-processing:

```
$('.textarea').bind('blur', function(){
    $('.textarea div').contents().unwrap().wrap('<p/>');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thNUS/4/

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is to simply replace any DIVs with Ps. Place this inside your content editable DIV.

```
onkeyup="this.innerHTML=this.innerHTML.replace('div','p')"
```

Hope it helps. Good luck.

Comment: you can replace the actual tags if you want to be specific and avoid potential conflicts with valid content. Just don't forget to replace the closing tags as well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with was to use [formatblock **which has compatibility issues**](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html#t012).  Basically you could add another link like so:

```
textcontainer.prepend("<button class='paragraph'>p</button>");
```

...

```
$(".paragraph").live("click", function(){
    document.execCommand('formatblock', false, "p");
});
```

This gives your users the option to insert a paragraph tag.  Getting out of that tag is a bit tricky though, so it has some usability issues too.  You can play with it on the provided demo:

**Demo**: http://jsbin.com/ovexiz/1
**Source**: http://jsbin.com/ovexiz/1/edit

*note that paragraphs are styled with green colored text.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers proposed a `keyup` or `blur` based solution. This one uses the `click` event of the list button to minimize the amount of function calls:

http://jsfiddle.net/9ZAL7/:

```
function replaceDivWithP(el){

    $(el).find('div').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($('<p>' + $(this).html() + '</p>'));
    });
}

$(function(){
    $(".text").simpleEdit();
});

$('button.list').bind('click', function(){
    replaceDivWithP($('.textarea'));
});
​
```