# How to move the carret in a contenteditable div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, events, contenteditable

I am trying to position the caret in a contenteditable div. The div does not have setSelectionRange or createTextRange. (I am using Chrome at the moment.)

So I tested if I could send keypress events instead:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress", { keyCode : 39} );
jQuery(myDiv).trigger(e);
```

It does not work. The event does not show up in the handler on myDiv. <= Wrong. It does show up in the listener, but the caret is not moved. (keyCode=39 is right arrow.)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the edit of the question, which is totally different to what you first asked, check this out:

[How to move cursor to end of contenteditable entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125292/how-to-move-cursor-to-end-of-contenteditable-entity/3866442#3866442)

Comment: Ah, fine. I missed that that example used createRange, not createTextRange. (Sorry if my question was unclear, but I think I did not change the question itself.)

Comment: Or, reading the question again I can see what you mean. ;-) "Change the caret position inside a div" would have been much better...

Answer (score 0):

The event should show up when you bind the handler before you trigger it:

```
(function($){
    $(function() {
        $('#foobar').keypress(function(event) {
            console.log(event.which);
        });

        var e = $.Event("keypress", { which : 39} );
        $('#foobar').trigger(e);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

this logs `39` in the console right when you visit the page.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vB2n/1/)

Comment: Thanks Alex, I just missed it in the log.

Comment: I'm not sure this is working (in terms of positioning the caret in the div) http://jsfiddle.net/chim/3vB2n/3/